# IoC в WPF по правилам MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, inversion-of-control, autofac

Постепенно начал изучать IoC и всю эту кухню и вот не как не могу понять, как работать с ними в WPF приложение по правилам MVVM.

Допустим я делаю некий класс настроек контейнера (использую Autofac):

```
class ContainerConfig
{
    public static IContainer Configure()
    {
        ISettings settings = new ConfigurationBuilder<ISettings>().UseJsonFile("Settings.json").Build();
        var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

        builder.RegisterType<MainViewModel>().SingleInstance();
        builder.RegisterInstance(settings).SingleInstance();

        return builder.Build();
    }
}
```

В нем я регистрирую пока 2 объекта:

1. `MainViewModel` - главная VM приложения, она я как понял должна быть в едином экземпляре.
2. Некий объект настроек приложения.

Далее переопределяю `OnStartup`, для того, что бы создать окно, задать ему `DataContext` и все это вывести:

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnStartup(e);
        var container = ContainerConfig.Configure();
        using var scope = container.BeginLifetimeScope();
        var mainViewModel = scope.Resolve<MainViewModel>();
        new MainWindow() { DataContext = mainViewModel }.Show();
    }
}
```

Вроде пока я двигаюсь в правильном направление, или нет?
Ок, дальше для проверки работы я просто привяжу свойство из настроек, написав в `MainViewModel` следующее:

```
class MainViewModel
{
    public ISettings Settings { get; }

    public MainViewModel(ISettings settingsModel)
    {
        Settings = settingsModel;
    }
}
```

И сама привязка:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Settings.SomeValue}"/>
```

Вроде все работает, все хорошо.
Теперь допустим мне надо сделать еще одну VM, которой например нужна главная VM, я делаю:

```
class SecondViewModel
{
    private MainViewModel main;
    public SecondViewModel(MainViewModel mainViewModel)
    {
        main = mainViewModel;
    }

    public int Test { get; set; } = 33;

    private void SomeMethod()
    {
        main.SomeProperty = false;
    }
}
```

Регистрирую его:

```
builder.RegisterType<SecondViewModel>().SingleInstance();
```

Ну и дописываю в `MainViewModel` новую VM:

```
class MainViewModel
{
    public ISettings Settings { get; }
    public SecondViewModel Second { get; }

    public MainViewModel(ISettings settingsModel, SecondViewModel second)
    {
        Settings = settingsModel;
        Second = second;
    }
}
```

В итоге получаю ошибку зацикленности и тут явно понимаю, что делаю что-то не так.
Немного поискав информацию, нашел [способ обхода](https://autofac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced/circular-dependencies.html).

Короче как видите, я не совсем до конца понимаю как все это должно работать и возникает куча вопросов, например:

1. Правильно я сделал выше?
2. Что должно регистрироваться в контейнере?
3. Необходимы-ли для VM слоев интерфейсы?
4. Как не нарушить MVVM?

В общем, помогите разобраться, **как все-же правильно реализовывать IoC в WPF приложение, да еще и с MVVM?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

DI контейнер - это инструмент, который делает за вас работу, которую вы и сами можете сделать, не нарушая никаких принципов.

Как вы знаете, контейнер - это такая вещь, которая создает обекты и следит за их временем жизни за вас.

Вы в своем коде создали 2 класса с цикличной зависимостью в конструкторе, что делает невозможным создание таких классов (если только в конструкторы NULL не передавать). Попробуйте создать ваши классы вручную и вы увидите, что у вас ничего не получится, так как, чтобы создать класс А, вам надо предоставить ему класс Б, а чтобы создать класс Б - вам надо предоставить класс А. Этот цикл и называется циклической зависимостью и его не так и просто побороть.

Но, как я сказал, побороть его не просто, но можно, например если определить фабрику для классов и передавать уже фабрику в конструктор. И то, это сработает, только если вы не попытаетесь обратиться к фабрике прямо внутри конструктора.

Например

```
class A
{
    IBFactory _bfactory;

    public A(IBFactory bfactory)
    {
        _bfactory = bfactory;
    }

    void Foo()
    {
        var b = _bfactory.GetB();
        // do stuff
    }
}

class B
{
    A _a;
    public B(A a)
    {
        _a = a;
    }
}

interface IBFactory{
    B GetB();
}
```

Реализация IBFactory может быть самой простой

```
class BFactory : IBFactory
{
    IContainer _container;

    public BFactory(IContainer container)
    {
        _container = container;
    }

    public B GetB(){
        return _container.Resolve<B>();
    }
}
```

Некоторые контейнеры, если мне память не изменяет, сами по себе поддерживают создание подобных фабрик. Ленивые же программисты в таком случае, вместо фабрики, пробрасывают просто весь контейнер в А класс, что черевато и является анти паттерном - service loсator.

Однако, также хочется сказать, что такие ситуации, когда подчиненная модель хочет знать о главной, в идеале, не должны существовать. Старайтесть проектировать такие VM, которые были бы максимально самодостаточные. В случае, если должна происходить комуникация между VM, то в общем случае для этого есть шина сообщений, или вы можете пробрасывать какие то свои интерфейсы, но вообще такая коммуникация должна быть ограничена. Чем меньше VM общаются друг с другом, тем меньше у вас головной боли при отладке.

Теперь давайте пойдем по вопросам:

> Правильно я сделал выше?

Нет ничего правильного в нашей профессии, но я бы решил вашу задачу иначе.

```
class SecondViewModel
{    
    public SecondViewModel()
    {        
    }

    event EventHandler<MyEventArgs> SomethingHappened;
    private void OnSomethingHappened(...) =>  SomethingHappened?.Invoke(....);

    ///......    

    private void SomeMethod()
    {
        OnSomethingHappened(...);      
    }
}

class MainViewModel
{
    public ISettings Settings { get; }
    public SecondViewModel Second { get; }

    public MainViewModel(ISettings settingsModel, SecondViewModel second)
    {
        Settings = settingsModel;
        Second = second;
        Second.SomethingHappened += Second_SomethingHappened;
    }

    private void Second_SomethingHappened(object sender, MyEventArgs args)
    {
        this.SomeProperty = false;
    }
}
```

Таким образом, вторая модель знать не знает ни о какой главной модели, а логика реакции главной модели на подчиненные модели хранится в одном месте - в главной модели.

> Что должно регистрироваться в контейнере?

Всё, что вы планируете использовать. Ваша проблема не в контейнере, а в орагнизации ваших классов - в циклической зависимости.

> Необходимы-ли для VM слоев интерфейсы?

Зависит от вашей органищации классов. Когда то это имеет смысл, когда то - не имеет (чаще не имеет). В вашей ситуации интерфейсы вам не помогут.

> Как не нарушить MVVM?

Вы оперируете здесь только с VM слоем, потому как бы вы этот слой не сделали, сам по себе он не нарушает MVVM.

Comment: Обычно (без IoC), моя главная VM выглядит примерно [так](https://pastebin.com/v7eEy63i), то есть она является связуещим звеном между всеми VM слоев, вот подобное хотел реализовать тут. Сейчас в билдер добавил ее таким образом `builder.RegisterType<MainViewModel>().SingleInstance().PropertiesAutowired(PropertyWiringOptions.AllowCircularDependencies);` и в самой VM оставил лишь необходимые свойства (без конструктора), вроде как работает, но не уверен в правильности данного решения.

Comment: Я тоже не уверен. У меня был унаследованный код точно такой же, как у вас, главная модель и много подчиненных (около 20-30), которые знают о главной модели. Дошло до того, что у меня была иерархия наследования моделей и базовые модели искали главную через контейнер а производные модели просто использовали функционал базовых как черный ящик. В итоге я столкнулся с тем, что во время отладки race condition проблемы я просто не мог сходу понять кто и как меняет мою основную модель , так как она менялась в 100500 местах. Отсюда и вылезли мои рекомендации в ответе.