# IoC в MVVM для чайников

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, инспекция-кода, inversion-of-control

Решил наконец-то научиться делать интерфейс приложений расширяемый на несколько View/ViewModel в рамках MVVM. Наткнулся на шаблон **Inversion of Control + Depency Injection**, информации по нему много, многие его советуют для огранизации логической архитектуры приложения. К тому же, он дает возможность организовать удобства типа хранилища синглтонов, которые мне как раз и нужны.

Проблема была в том, что в статьях авторы рекомендуют [вот это вот всё](https://www.palmmedia.de/Blog/2011/8/30/ioc-container-benchmark-performance-comparison), и практически никто не показывает реализацию IoC вручную в WPF+MVVM "для чайников".

А я не могу не понимая, как оно работает, использовать "черный ящик" в своих проектах, вообще не люблю большое, срашное и непонятное, которое непонятно как работает, и всегда пытаюсь раскопать эту самую суть. Разбор решил выполнить на практической задаче - сделать многостраничный интерфейс с `ListBox` для выбора страниц.

Начал с двух интефейсов

```cs
public interface IView
{
    string Title { get; set; }
    object DataContext { get; set; }
}

public interface IViewModel
{
}
```

Затем прикрутил их все

```csharp
public sealed partial class MainWindow : Window, IView {...}
public partial class Page1 : Page, IView {...}
public partial class Page2 : Page, IView {...}

public class MainViewModel : NotifyPropertyChanged, IViewModel {...}
public class Page1ViewModel : NotifyPropertyChanged, IViewModel {...}
public class Page2ViewModel : NotifyPropertyChanged, IViewModel {...}
```

И реализовал вот такие 2 контейнера с синглтонами

```cs
public static class ViewService
{
    private static readonly ConcurrentDictionary<Type, IView> instances = new ConcurrentDictionary<Type, IView>();

    public static T GetView<T>(IViewModel viewModel = null) where T : IView
    {
        if (!instances.TryGetValue(typeof(T), out IView view))
        {
            view = (T)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T));
            instances[typeof(T)] = view;
        }
        if (viewModel != null)
            view.DataContext = viewModel;
        return (T)view;
    }
}

public static class ViewModelService
{
    private static readonly ConcurrentDictionary<Type, IViewModel> instances = new ConcurrentDictionary<Type, IViewModel>();

    public static T GetViewModel<T>() where T : IViewModel
    {
        if (!instances.TryGetValue(typeof(T), out IViewModel viewModel))
        {
            viewModel = (T)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T));
            instances[typeof(T)] = viewModel;
        }
        return (T)viewModel;
    }
}
```

Главное окно создаю вот так

```cs
public partial class App : Application
{
    protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnStartup(e);
        MainViewModel vm = ViewModelService.GetViewModel<MainViewModel>();
        MainWindow window = ViewService.GetView<MainWindow>(vm);
        window.Show();
    }
}
```

А странички - в конструкторе главной вью-модели

```cs
public class MainViewModel : NotifyPropertyChanged, IViewModel
{
    private IView _currentPage;

    public List<IView> Pages { get; }

    public IView CurrentPage
    {
        get => _currentPage;
        set
        {
            _currentPage = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Title));
        }
    }

    public string Title => $"IoC Demo - {CurrentPage.Title}";

    public MainViewModel()
    {
        Pages = new List<IView>
        {
            ViewService.GetView<Page1>(ViewModelService.GetViewModel<Page1ViewModel>()),
            ViewService.GetView<Page2>(ViewModelService.GetViewModel<Page2ViewModel>())
        };
        CurrentPage = Pages[0];
    }
}
```

Главное окно `MainWindow`

```xml
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ListBox BorderThickness="0" Background="AliceBlue" ItemsSource="{Binding Pages}" SelectedItem="{Binding CurrentPage}">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="5"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
    <Frame Content="{Binding CurrentPage}" Grid.Column="1" NavigationUIVisibility="Hidden"/>
</Grid>
```

Странички одинаковые, просто у одной тип `Page1`, у второй `Page2`

```xml
<Grid>
    <TextBlock Margin="5" Text="{Binding Text}"/>
</Grid>
```

Вью-модель странички (для видимости)

```cs
public class Page1ViewModel : NotifyPropertyChanged, IViewModel
{
    public string Text { get; } = "Page one";
}
```

И это все вместе работает.

**Вопрос:** Нарушаю ли я MVVM, и правильно ли реализовал IoC контейнеры с синглтонами?

[image: IoC WPF]

**P.S.**

- *[IoC в WPF по правилам MVVM](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1080537/373567) от @EvgeniyZ и @tym32167 я уже читал. Было полезно, спасибо!*

Comment: А почему статика? Контейнер должен создаваться один раз при старте приложения, забиваться нужными объектами/типами и дальше через него уже получается все что нужно. Также не пойму для чего вам два контейнера, почему не один? Ну и также я не вижу у вас тут DI, к примеру, у вас есть `HttpClient` отдельно, в виде сервиса, вам его надо достать в `Page1`, вы пишете `private HttpClientService client; public Page1(HttpClientService service) {this.service = service;}` и все, ваше приложение падает, когда контейнер должен сам выдать этот `HttpClientService`.

Comment: Вот это, `Pages = new List<IView>`, по сути тоже должен делать контейнер за вас. По поводу нарушений - да по сути сама `Frame` сильно ограничивает MVVM и не редко его нарушает, а так, кроме того, что у вас за `DataContext` отвечает контейнер, мне лично придраться не к чему. Могу посоветовать вам [этот](https://www.calabonga.net/blog/post/dependency-container-custom-implementation) материал, который мне однажды очень хорошо помог в понимание как устроены IoC.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Спасибо! 1) Почему статика, потому что я не вижу причин для синглтона здесь, я никому и никуда сам контейнер не передаю, он просто статичный, и он просто есть. 2) `view.DataContext = viewModel;` - **Property DI**, разве нет? 3) Почему два контейнера: можно свалить это в один класс, можно даже сотворить один метод, но я не хотел усложнять синтаксис передачей двух типов в метод, так сказать, двойной дженерик. Поэтому разделил.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ 4) По поводу `new List<IView>` - просто посадить в `getter` что-то типа `get => ViewService.GetAllViews<Page>();`? Но там еще **View** главного окна болтается, не получится ли лишних плясок вокруг выфильтровывания `Page` из контейнера? В общем, пока не придумал, что можно изменить. И не понял, куда и зачем унести из контейнера `DataContext`. Спасибо за ссылку.

Comment: Вот ещё [немного текста почитать](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/905310/179763)

Comment: а вообще в вашем примере я вижу фабрики, но не вижу DI

Comment: Возьмем, например, вашу главную модель. Почему она решает какие страницы, какого типа и сколько надо отрендерить? Почему нельзя эти страницы создать заранее и закинуть в конструктор? Или делегировать это создание другому классу?

Comment: Ваши сервисы для создания являются обычными фабриками. Вы, конечно, можете попробовать натянуть на них название "DI контейнер", но выполнять роль контейнера они не начнут от этого. Также пример не очень удачный, так как хранить представления в памяти я бы не стал - другое окно может захотеть предсталение забрать себе и можно получить непонятную кашу. Обычно можно хранить VM как синглтон, а представление рендерить каждый раз, когда неадо показать VM

Comment: По поводу [отображения разных представлений в одном контейнере](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/765122/179763)

Comment: 1) Ну статика, если вам так удобней, и вы так видите, то дерзайте, но, если вы возьмете, например AutoFac или любой другой контейнер, то вы не увидите там статику вовсе, ибо у них другой жизненный цикл. Судить плохо это или нет, не буду, лично для меня статика зло) И не путайте жизненный цикл контейнера и объекта, внутри него.2) Вы, по сути, просто взяли объект и установили ему свойство. Это больше и правда похоже на фабрику. 3) Сама суть IoC в том, что появляется некий механизм, который отвечает за инициализацию объектов и внедрение в них необходимых зависимостей.

Comment: 4) [Как это сделано у AutoFac](https://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/resolve/relationships.html#enumeration-ienumerable-b-ilist-b-icollection-b), но как реализовано, увы, подсказать не смогу.
По поводу лишних плясок - IoC заменяет `var first = new First(); var second = new Second(first);`, он делает это за вас, вам необходимо лишь зарезолвить один раз главный объект, который в последующем, при помощи DI будет получать все необходимое для него. Саму структуру приложения это, по сути, не меняет, меняет лишь подход в некоторых местах.

Comment: @tym32167 справедливое замечание, одну и ту же вьюху действительно нельзя показывать одновременно больше, чем один раз. Но у меня это в принципе невозможно, но я пометил себе негибкость решения, учту обязательно. Спасибо!

Comment: @EvgeniyZ подумал, таки перенес `DataContext`, обновил вопрос.

Comment: Ну так вы саму суть то не поменяли, у вас как была фабрика, которая по требованию отдает нужный объект, так и осталась. В IoC вы изначально создаете контейнер, в него регистрируете все свои необходимые типы, дальше говорите ему: "Слушай, дай мне главный класс и запихни в него все зависимости". Он вам отдает, например `MainViewModel`, которая требует для своей работы некий `ILogger`, вам не нужно будет писать `ILogger = Container.Resolve(...);`, это за вас уже сам контейнер сделает. Вот простой [пример](https://dotnetfiddle.net/o5w4yg) набросал. Заметьте, что внутри классов не делается Resolve.

Comment: То есть, в вашем примере, достаточно из контейнера зарезолвить только `MainViewModel`, ну и окно (а должно-ли оно быть в контейнере?), задать один раз ее как `DataContext` и все, дальше вы забываете про контейнер (только если не надо зарегистрировать новый тип), вы просто пишете классы, с нужными для них зависимостями, а контейнер сам проинициализирует и подставит.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Кажется, осилил.

1. Конструкторы изменил так, чтобы они принимали конкретный тип View Model и закидывали его себе в `DataContext`.

```cs
public MainWindow(MainViewModel viewModel) {...}
public Page1(Page1ViewModel viewModel) {...}
public Page2(Page2ViewModel viewModel) {...}
```

2. Интерфейс `IViewModel` выкинул за ненадобностью
3. Реализовал IoC контейнер, на этот раз надеюсь, что настоящий

```cs
public static class IocContainer
{
    private static readonly IDictionary<Type, object> instances = new ConcurrentDictionary<Type, object>();

    public static void Register<T>() where T : class
        => instances[typeof(T)] = null;

    public static T Resolve<T>() where T : class
        => (T)GetInstance(typeof(T));

    private static object GetInstance(Type type)
    {
        bool registered = instances.TryGetValue(type, out object instance);
        if (instance == null)
        {
            object[] args = type.GetConstructors().First().GetParameters().Select(x => GetInstance(x.ParameterType)).ToArray();
            instance = Activator.CreateInstance(type, args);
            if (registered)
                instances[type] = instance;
        }
        return instance;
    }
}
```

4. Код `OnStartup` теперь выглядит так:

```cs
protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnStartup(e);
    IocContainer.Register<MainViewModel>();
    IocContainer.Register<Page1ViewModel>();
    IocContainer.Register<Page2ViewModel>();

    IocContainer.Resolve<MainWindow>().Show();
}
```

5. А конструктор `MainViewModel` так:

```cs
public MainViewModel()
{
    Pages = new List<IView>
    {
        IocContainer.Resolve<Page1>(),
        IocContainer.Resolve<Page2>()
    };
    CurrentPage = Pages[0];
}
```

Спасибо всем комментаторам, накачали меня действительно нужной информацией, особенно [SimpleIoC](https://www.calabonga.net/blog/post/dependency-container-custom-implementation) помог.

**P.S.** *Архив с этим решением на Яндекс.Диске - [ссылка](https://yadi.sk/d/WqMBGw5bdFAW2Q).*

Comment: Уже лучше, хоть на базовый контейнер стало похоже, но вот статика и постоянный резолв страниц мне не очень нравиться. В Autofac подобное выглядело бы [так](https://dotnetfiddle.net/f2oO0C), то есть регистрируются нужные типы под нужным интерфейсом, а потом просим контейнер отдать нам все типы, которые реализуют нужный интерфейс и как видите, опять без резолва внутри классов.  Вот эту бы фичу вам стянуть оттуда, раз пишете свой IoC. Вот кстати не знаю, правильно-ли вообще резолв делать внутри класса, не разу подобного не видел, ибо как я говорил ранее, это задача контейнера, отдать зависимости.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ да, я понял, что полноценный контейнер может всякое, но у меня нет задачи написать полноценный контейнер, который может горы свернуть и позволит обмазаться юнит-тестами. У меня была задача прикрутить IoC к приложению так, чтобы меня за нарушение MVVM не сожгли на костре. А главное - я понял, как это работает, и теперь такой контейнер смогу без гугла воспроизвести сам с нуля. Новичкам, кто не в теме, возможно тоже мой код пригодится. А вам - еще раз спасибо! Про интерфейсы понял, прикольно, завтра поковыряюсь, но это уже за рамками данного вопроса.

Comment: Это какой-то неправильный MVVM получается. И ссылки на вид внутри вьюмоделей и IoC внутри вьюмоделей а-ка сервис локатор.

Comment: @vitidev это была проба пера в целях обучения, я уже на Autofac переехал. Там все как вы говорите получилось.

Comment: ну если MVVM+IoC, да autofac, то можете попробовать сразу [подальше](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZzmK7K2ZIxI) зайти.

Comment: Забыл еще [этот крутой доклад](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Sq_h5bVWJ0k) (я использую их решение) для понимания мощи подхода. Это выворачивает управление времени жизни vm - не контейнер управляет временем жизни, а наоборот.. Как следствие, weakref не нужен (а в MVVM их хватает и проблемы они не решают) и всё (RelayCommand, PropertyObserver, Messenger и события) используется с lifetime, и когда lifetime, в котором живет vm, схлопывается, то автоматически все отписывается и чистится. Если вы в самом начале интеграции IoC, то у вас есть возможность встроить IoC с бОльшим профитом.