# Рефлексия c#. Можно ли узнать входные параметры, которые использовались при создании экземпляра?

Tags: c#, классы, рефлексия

В общем смысле, мне нужно получть от входного объекта его конструктор и список параметров. Самое главное - список параметров. Возможно ли реализовать что-то подобное:

```
Class Prime
{
Type t;
obj[] param;
public void addobj(object obj)
{
     t = obj.GetType();
    param = obj.GetParameter();
}

public object createobj()
{
    return Activators.CreateInstanse(t,param)

}
}
```

Чтобы вызов adobj выглядел следующим образом:

```
addobj(new Person("Vasya", 17);
```

Comment: Вот [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1185026/373567) я игрался с этой темой.

Comment: невозможно узнать с помощью какого именно конструктора был создан объект, можно лишь получить список всех конструкторов указанного типа, из конструкторов, соответственно типы параметров

Comment: а что вы пытаетесь решить таким кодом? т.к. сейчас это выглядит очень странно, вы передаете уже созданный объект, чтобы потом создать его через `Activator`?

Comment: @ExplodingKitten, не его, а новый объект, с такими же параметрами

Comment: @ExplodingKitten создать список историии объектов, чтобы хранились не их экемпляры, а их "шаблоны".

Comment: Можете более конкретный пример привести? Пока выглядит так, что решения нет. Быть может на более высоком уровне вы выбрали неверный подход к решению. Расскажите задачу с примером. Напишитп аоспроизводимый пример, например на базе консольного приложения, покажите его нам.

Comment: а вам нужно хранить историю для любого типа объекта?

Comment: если для конкретных типов, выглядит как паттерн Memento, вы сохраняете внутреннее состояние в некую структуру, а в будущем, можете создать новый объект из этой структуры, и это все можно сделать не раскрывая реализацию объекта

Comment: @aepot , у меня был предыдущий вопрос на эту тему. Там я смогла реализовать то, что хотела. Единственным минусом, как по мне, являлось то, что необходимо было выводить новый тип данных для аргументов, и хранить обработку в конструкторах классов.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Аргументы метода передаются через стек, т.е. по окончанию вызова конструктора о параметрах, переданных в него, ничего не известно. Чтобы узнать, какие аргументы были переданы в конструктор есть несколько способов.

**Кэширование**

Зачастую аргументы, передаваемые в конструктор, сохраняются в полях новосозданного объекта. С помощью рефлексии мы можем изъять эти поля. Лично я данный метод не рекомендую, т.к. вы должны знать внутреннее устройство типа, а т.к. эти поля, обычно, приватные, то метаданные о них от версии к версии могут меняться.

```cs
public sealed class Some
{
    readonly int x;

    public Some(int x)
    {
        this.x = x;
    }
}
```

```cs
static void Main()
{
    var some = new Some(5);

    // проверки опущены
    Console.WriteLine(some.GetField("x").GetValue(some)); // 5
}
```

**Сохранить аргументы локально**

Можно сохранить аргументы локально в стеке метода, вызывающего конструктор. Это самый простой и безопасный способ.

```cs
public sealed class Node
{
    readonly Node? next;

    public Node(Node? next = null)
    {
        this.next = next;
    }
}
```

```cs
static void Main()
{
    var next = new Node();
    var node = new Node(next);

    // `next` - это и есть аргумент 2-го конструктора
}
```

**Прокси-класс**

Если уж очень хочется сохранить аргументы глобально, при этом не вскрывая класс изнутри, то можно использовать прокси-класс.

```cs
public sealed class Some
{
    readonly int a, b, c;

    public Some(int a, int b, int c)
    {
        (this.a, this.b, this.c) = (a, b, c);
    }
}
```

```cs
public sealed class SomeProxy
{
    public Some Instance { get; }
    public int PassedA { get; }
    public int PassedB { get; }
    public int PassedC { get; }

    public SomeProxy(int a, int b, int c)
    {
        Instance = new Some(a, b, c);
        (PassedA, PassedB, PassedC) = (a, b, c);
    }
}
```

```cs
public interface ISomeOwner : IDisposable
{
    Some Instance { get; }

    void Remove();
}
public class SomeStorage
{
    readonly LinkedList<SomeProxy> proxies;

    ⋮

    public ISomeOwner Add(int a, int b, int c)
    {
        var proxy = new SomeProxy(a, b, c);
        var node = proxies.Add(proxy);

        ⋮

        return new SomeOwner(proxy.Instance, node);
    }

    ⋮

    seales class SomeOwner : ISomeOwner
    {
        internal SomeOwner(Some some, LinkedListNode<Some> node)
        {
            ⋮
        }

        ⋮
    }
}
```

<sup>**Важно!** Это псевдо-код. Вам не следует его копировать в проекты для релиза.</sup>

После создания и добавления объекта типа `Some` в наше заранее созданное хранилище мы можем обращаться к аргументам, переданным в его конструктор, с помощью получения их из соответствующего `SomeProxy`.

---

В итоге вполне простыми способами мы можем реализовать хранение аргументов конструктора в самом классе, во внешних локальном и глобальном хранилищах. Способ выбирайте сами в зависимости от вашей ситуации.

---

Получить конструктор от объекта заренее известного типа довольно просто, но если вы хотите получить его от generic'а, то тут придётся постараться. Это я про 3-й способ — `SomeProxy`. Его можно заменить на вот такой класс:

```cs
public sealed class Proxy<out T>
{
    public T Instance { get; }
    public ConstructorInfo UsedConstructor { get; }
    public IReadOnlyList<object?> PassedArgs { get; }

    public Proxy(params object?[]? args)
    {
        if (!FindConstructor(out var ctor, args)) throw new ArgumentException("Suitable constructor not found", nameof(args));

        UsedConstructor = ctor;
        PassedArgs = new ReadOnlyCollection<object?>(args ?? Array.Empty<object?>);
        Instance = UsedConstructor.Invoke(PassedArgs);
    }
    
    static bool FindConstructorByArgs([MaybeNullWhen(false)] out ConstructorInfo constructor, params object?[]? args)
    {
        constructor = null!;

        var ctorArgTypes = args is null ? Array.Empty<Type?>() :
            args.Select(a => a is null ? null : a.GetType());
        var ctors = typeof(T).GetConstructors();
        ConstructorInfo? ctor = null;

        foreach (var _ctor in ctors)
        {
            var args = _ctor.GetParameters();

            if (args.Length != ctorArgTypes.Length) continue;

            for (var i = 0; i < args.Length; i++)
            {
                if (ctorArgTypes[i] is null &&
                    args[i].ParameterType != typeof(Nullable<>) &&
                    args[i].ParameterType.IsValueType)
                    continue;
                if (args[i].ParameterType != ctorArgTypes[i])
                    continue;
            }

            ctor = _ctor;

            break;
        }

        if (ctor is null) return false;

        constructor = ctor;

        return true;
    }
}
```