# Использование Ninject в MVVM-приложении

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, ninject

Доброго времени суток!

Пишу WPF-приложение и хочу использовать Dependancy Injection. Однако, не могу использовать MVVM из-за того, что не получается каким-либо образом ввести зависимость во ViewModel. Свойство `DataContext` для окон задаю в XAML-разметке, поэтому если моя ViewModel имеет внедрение зависимости через конструктор, то получаю постоянно `NullReferenceException`.

В принципе, более-менее работает вариант с установкой `DataContext` через codeBehind окна, но из-за этого теряются многие удобные фичи XAML-редактора VS.

Сейчас мой код выглядит так:

App.xaml.cs:

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    private IKernel container;

    protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnStartup(e);
        container = new StandardKernel();
        container.Load(new Common.ReminderModule());

        Current.MainWindow = this.container.Get<MainWindow>();
        Current.MainWindow.Title = "DI with Ninject";
        Current.MainWindow.Show();
    }

    public IKernel GetContainer()
    {
        return container;
    }
}
```

MainWindow.xaml.cs

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private readonly ICoreStorage coreStorage;
    public MainWindow(ICoreStorage coreStorage)
    {
        this.coreStorage = coreStorage;
        DataContext = new MainWindowViewModel(this.coreStorage);
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

MainWindowViewModel.cs

```
public class MainWindowViewModel:ViewModelBase
{
    private readonly ICoreStorage coreStorage;
    private ObservableCollection<ICompany> companies = new ObservableCollection<ICompany>();


    public MainWindowViewModel(ICoreStorage coreStorage)
    {
        this.coreStorage = coreStorage;
        GetCompanies();
    }        

    public ObservableCollection<ICompany> Companies
    {
        get { return companies; }
        set { companies = value; RaisePropertyChanged("Companies"); }
    }


    private async void GetCompanies()
    {
        Companies.Clear();
        foreach( var company in await coreStorage.GetCompanyStorage("D:\\Tests\\Reminder").GetCompanies())
        {
            Companies.Add(company);
            RaisePropertyChanged("Companies");
        }
    }
}
```

Мой вопрос больше концептуальный. Правильно ли я использую Ninject? Есть ли способ передать зависимость во ViewModel, если она определяется через разметку? И есть ли какие-то best practises для  использования DI в MVVM-приложениях?

Comment: [DataContext в XAML плохо!](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/562586/220553). `теряются многие удобные фичи XAML-редактора` - пишем `d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance {x:Type тип}}"` и радуемся.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Дисклеймер:** Я не буду использовать Ninject в ответе.*

Попробую ответить простыми словами, так как сам совсем недавно узнал, как работает IoC+DI. Тема очень популярная, но сходу в ней разобраться не так-то просто. Мне помогли другие участники StackOverflow, за что им спасибо. Пытался вникнуть в тему я [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1184712/373567) *(вопрос по ссылке был задан именно с целью разобраться, как работает IoC контейнер, ну или хотя-бы базовая его часть, практической ценности в вопросе мало, ознакомьтесь, если пока не понимаете, как работает DI+IoC изнутри)*.

Сам я выбрал контейнер **Autofac**, поэтому пример покажу с ним. Ninject тоже рассматривал, но там непонятная история с производительностью, у контейнера не идеальная репутация. Альтернативно рассматривал Unity контейнер, но остановился именно на Autofac.

Так как у вас есть ошибки при реализации приложения, начну с них и в самом конце расскажу про XAML-проблему.

Класс окна выглядит вот так

```cs
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow(MainWindowViewModel viewModel)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = viewModel;
    }
}
```

Всё, я не увидел ни одной причины инжектить сюда `ICoreStorage`.

*Никогда не вставляйте код, взаимодействующий с внешними источниками данных в конструкторы окна или вьюмодели, так как и тот и другой здесь может сломать вам приложение и вызвать непредсказуемое поведение.*

В конструкторе окна можно взаимодействовать только с контролами этого же самого окна. В конструкторе ViewModel можно взаимодействовать только с полями и свойствами, присутствующими внутри класса. Если некоторые свойства требуют внешних данных для инициализации, их нельзя инициализировать в конструкторе.

И вот всё что я сказал про ограничения для конструктора окна - в MVVM относится ко всему классу окна. Если пишете код-бихайнд, делайте это так, чтобы не обращаться к данным (вообще к любым), работайте в код-бихайнде исключительно только с контролами и их свойствами. Я бы даже сказал, ограничьтесь тем, что имеете внутри обработчика события (`sender`, `e`), старайтесь не обращаться к тому, что за его пределами. Тогда почти наверняка не будет нарушен MVVM.

Теперь вьюмодель.

```cs
public class MainWindowViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    // если поля называть с _подчеркивания, не придется везде втыкать this, но дело вкуса.
    private readonly ICoreStorage _coreStorage;
    private ObservableCollection<ICompany> _companies;

    public MainWindowViewModel(ICoreStorage coreStorage)
    {
        _coreStorage = coreStorage;
    }        

    public ObservableCollection<ICompany> Companies
    {
        get { return _companies; }
        set { _companies = value; RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(Companies)); }
    }

    public async Task GetCompanies()
    {
        // у вас в BaseViewModel реализован INotifyPropertyChanged, поэтому можно просто вот так
        var companies = await coreStorage.GetCompanyStorage(@"D:\Tests\Reminder").GetCompanies();
        Companies = new ObservableCollection(companies);
    }
}
```

Теперь Composition Root - точка сборки приложения из классов, которая у вас, да и у меня расположена в `OnStartup()`.

```cs
using Autofac;
```

```cs
protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnStartup(e);

    // регистрация классов
    ContainerBuilder builder = new ContainerBuilder();
    builder.RegisterType<CoreStorage>().As<ICoreStorage>().SingleInstance();
    builder.RegisterType<MainWindowViewModel>().SingleInstance();
    builder.RegisterType<MainWindow>();

    // поехали
    IContainer container = builder.Build();
    MainWindow window = container.Resolve<MainWindow>();
    window.Loaded += async (s, e) =>
    {
       try
       {
           await ((MainWindowViewModel)window.DataContext).GetCompanies();
       }
       catch (Exception ex)
       {
           // всегда обрабатывайте все возможные исключения для async void методов, иначе вы попросту их не увидите
           Debug.Fail(ex.Message);
       }
    }
    window.Show();
}
```

Нет никакой нужды трогать здесь `Application.Current.MainWindow`, WPF сделает это за вас.

Событие `Window.Loaded` подходит для загрузки данных из внешних источников намного лучше, чем конструктор. В данном случае как минимум потому что обработчик события можно сделать асинхронным и обработать в нем исключение, в конструкторе такой фокус не прокатит.

Теперь, что же делать с подсказками в XAML редакторе, а ему нужно просто показать, какой тип будет у `DataContext`.

```xml
<Window x:Class="..."
        ...
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:..."
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance local:MainWindowViewModel}">
```

И всё, теперь IntelliSense вам будет подсказывать, где там какие свойства у вьюмодели для биндингов.