# Навигация в приложении, с частичной сменой View

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Как можно добиться навигации, так, чтобы по кликам на боковые кнопки (1, 2, 3 слева), происходила смена view справа?

Научился делать смену всего контента в окне, через navigationService при помощи MvvmCross, а вот с частичной не могу разобраться.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Навигацию сделать легко, а при чем тут MvvmCross? Покажите разметку и код, и расскажите, что именно не получается? У меня есть пример решения, но на базе IoC контейнера Autofac и без MvvmCross.

Comment: MvvmCross здесь просто для того, что хочется изучить его систему навигации. Я понимаю, что есть разные способы реализации моего вопроса. Также предполагаю, что нет особого смысла прикладывать код, т.к. кроме двух вьюх и вью моделей там больше ничего нет. Я больше хотел получить пример реализации кастомного presenter'а, как это делается в MvvmCross (если все правильно понял)

Comment: Здесь на самом деле есть примеры, но они практически все нарушают MVVM, загоняя список страниц `Page` в ViewModel и привязывая к ним левый листбокс, который представляет из себя меню. Поэтому пока я ссылок не дам. А контентпрезентер здесь особо не при чем, для навигации между `Page` используется `<Frame>`. Сейчас пытаюсь прикрутить это всё без нарушения MVVM и кучи кода, а нативными для WPF+MVVM методами. Если получится, скину пример.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Здесь много примеров реализации многостраничного интерфейса, в основном на базе `Frame`+`Page`. Но самый простой, и с виду самый адекватный способ использования этой конструкции нарушает MVVM, потому что коллекцию `List<Page>` придется хранить в ViewModel, то есть View внутри ViewModel, а VM не должна отвечать за View в MVVM. Это так же пораждает путаницу. Для активной страницы придется выдергивать `DataContext`, чтобы получить текущую VM страницы в главной VM и еще много других приключений. Базовый способ использования `Frame`+`Page` есть в [этом ответе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1185026/373567).

Но я предлагаю пойти немного другим путем. В качестве View я предлагаю использовать не какой-либо `Control`, а просто xaml разметку без кодбиханда - `DataTemplate`, помещаемый в `ResourceDictionary`.

Структура проекта

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Так как я не использую MVVM фреймворки, у меня есть класс, реализующий `INotifyPropertyChanged`, но вы его можете заменить на `ViewModelBase`, или что там у вас.

**NotifyPropertyChanged.cs**

```cs
public class NotifyPropertyChanged : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        => PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
}
```

Создаем 2 View и 2 ViewModel для страничек, они будут одинаковые, поэтому я покажу только первую.

**View1.xaml**

```xml
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
                    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
                    mc:Ignorable="d"
                    xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:WpfIoC.ViewModels;assembly=WpfIoC">
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:Page1ViewModel}">
        <Grid d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance vm:Page1ViewModel}">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Text}"/>
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

**Page1ViewModel.cs**

```cs
public class Page1ViewModel : NotifyPropertyChanged, IPageViewModel
{
    public string Title => "Page1";
    public string Text => "Page one";
}
```

Ах, да, интерфейс

**IPageViewModel.cs**

```cs
public interface IPageViewModel
{
    string Title { get; }
}
```

Интерфейс этот нужен, чтобы можно было засунуть все вьюмодели в один список, ну и чтобы иметь доступ к заголовку странички.

Далее, главное окно

**MainWindow.xaml**

```xml
<Window x:Class="WpfIoC.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:WpfIoC.ViewModels"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Height="400" Width="600"
        d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance vm:MainViewModel, IsDesignTimeCreatable=True}"
        Title="{Binding Title}">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ListBox BorderThickness="0" Background="AliceBlue" ItemsSource="{Binding PageViewModels}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedPageViewModel}" SelectedIndex="0" MinWidth="40">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="5"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
        <ContentPresenter Grid.Column="1" Content="{Binding SelectedPageViewModel}"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

В код-бихайнде ничего нет

**MainViewWindow.xaml.cs**

```cs
public sealed partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

И его вьюмодель

**MainViewModel.cs**

```cs
public class MainViewModel : NotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private IPageViewModel _selectedPageViewModel;
    private IList<IPageViewModel> _pageViewModels;

    public string Title => $"MultiPage demo - {SelectedPageViewModel?.Title}";

    public IList<IPageViewModel> PageViewModels
    {
        get => _pageViewModels;
        set
        {
            _pageViewModels = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public IPageViewModel SelectedPageViewModel 
    {
        get => _selectedPageViewModel; 
        set 
        {
            _selectedPageViewModel = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Title));
        } 
    }
}
```

Как видите, ничего сверъестественного, но самое главное - **точка компоновки приложения** (Composition Root), это место, куда вам надо подключать разные части приложения и собирать их в единое целое. Сами по себе эти части друг о друге мало чего знают, или ничего вовсе не знают. Это позволяет разрабатывать приложение модульно. Слабые зависимости между различнвми компонентами приложения дают больше свободы при доработке отдельных компонент.

Для компоновки я выбрал 2 файла:

**App.xaml**

```xml
<Application x:Class="WpfIoC.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="Views/View1.xaml"/>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="Views/View2.xaml"/>
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

Здесь как раз и прикручиваются `DataTemplate` к приложению.

**App.xaml.cs**

```cs
public partial class App : Application
{
    protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnStartup(e);

        new MainWindow
        {
            DataContext = new MainViewModel
            {
                PageViewModels = new List<IPageViewModel>
                {
                    new Page1ViewModel(),
                    new Page2ViewModel()
                }
            }
        }.Show();
    }
}
```

А здесь все компоненты собираются в одно целое и запускаются.

Но я предпочитаю код компоновки реализовывать с помощью IoC контейнера (Autofac). Несмотря на то что код сборки именно этого приложения выглядит сложнее, контейнер умеет много всего, и пример здесь собран так, чтобы всё связанное с контейнером было в одном файле, через инициализацию свойств. В обычном же случае я использую конструкторы для внедрения зависимостей, а не свойства, тогда код выглядит проще.

**App.xaml.cs**

```cs
public partial class App : Application
{
    protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnStartup(e);
        ContainerBuilder builder = new ContainerBuilder();

        builder.RegisterType<Page1ViewModel>().As<IPageViewModel>().SingleInstance();
        builder.RegisterType<Page2ViewModel>().As<IPageViewModel>().SingleInstance();
        builder.RegisterType<MainViewModel>().OnActivating(e => e.Instance.PageViewModels = e.Context.Resolve<IList<IPageViewModel>>()).SingleInstance();

        builder.RegisterType<MainWindow>().OnActivating(e => e.Instance.DataContext = e.Context.Resolve<MainViewModel>());
        IContainer container = builder.Build();

        using ILifetimeScope scope = container.BeginLifetimeScope();
        scope.Resolve<MainWindow>().Show();
    }
}
```

**Готово.**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если захотите воткнуть юзерконтрол в качестве View, просто вставьте его в нужный `DataTemplate`.

Comment: Спасибо большое за столь подробный ответ. Вы действительно можете убедить использовать стандартные свойства WPF :-)

Comment: @chesh111re ну `Page`+`Frame` тоже весьма стандартные, только кривоват у них дизайн для MVVM. Я именно с этой парочки и начал путь к решению.

Comment: @eapot А я правильно понимаю, что в классе App, нужно регистрировать все имеющиеся ViewModel'и?

Comment: @chesh111re это просто точка сборки словарей ресурсов. Вы можете их собрать хоть в окне, хоть в еще одном словаре в отдельном файле, а потом подключать куда надо. Я скорее предложил технологию и способ ее использования. Вам решать, где именно вы подключите xaml файлы.

Comment: @chesh111re Вы тогда вопрос редактируйте, чтоб там не было какого-либо упоминания фреймворка, а то сейчас этот ответ банально не в тему, ибо `но хотелось бы разобраться с MvvmCross`, а в итоге приняли ответ, где все идет в разрез фреймворка...

Comment: @EvgeniyZ согласен, сейчас поправлю

Comment: @aepot `xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:WpfIoC.ViewModels;assembly=WpfIoC"` можно про это узнать? ибо в `DataTemplate` ругается на viewmodel созданную UPD: уже понял UPD2: но все равно ругается на `DataType`

Comment: @gwgw бывает xaml глючит, надо пересобрать приложение, после пересборки, если не помоло, перезапустить студию. А вообще это просто неймспейс и класс.

Comment: @aepot  
**1.** Ваше решение подразумевает пердачу данных из `Page1ViewModel` в `Page2ViewModel`?
Или нужно дополнительные классы создавать?
Если несложно опишите в двух словах что нужно сделать...
Пример: из `Page1ViewModel.Property1` передать в `Page2ViewModel.Property2`.

Comment: @eusataf а зачем что-либо передавать, если можно просто через конструктор в VM1 получить экземпляр VM2 и просто иметь к ней прямой доступ. Моё решение не про передачу данных, а про сборку логики приложения. И вообще "передача" здесь некорректно, правильнее "доступ".

Answer (score 2):

У меня есть более элегантное решение. Как мне кажется. Действовать мы будем в рамках WPF MVVM Frame + Page. Для примера создаем главное окно и три странички.

Структура XAML главного окна:

```
    <Grid Grid.Row="1">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition MaxWidth="150" MinWidth="150"/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <!--#region Menu panel-->
        <Grid Grid.Column="0">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition MaxHeight="40"/>
                <RowDefinition MaxHeight="530"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

            <StackPanel Grid.Row="1">
                <RadioButton Command="{Binding ChangePageCommand}" CommandParameter="1"/>
                <RadioButton Command="{Binding ChangePageCommand}" CommandParameter="2"/>
                <RadioButton Command="{Binding ChangePageCommand}" CommandParameter="3"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </Grid>
        <!--#endregion-->

        <Frame Grid.Column="1"
               NavigationUIVisibility="Hidden"
               Content="{Binding CurrentPage}"/>
    </Grid>
```

Здесь мы описываем Grid на подобии твоего рисунка. Заместо RadioButton можно использовать простой Button, но как по мне так более логично. Следом Биндим команду ChangePageCommand с параметром (главное отличным от другого). После чего, во второй столбец грида закидываем элемент Frame (он нужен для отображения страниц) и тут же биндимся к CurrentPage. (ПОЗЖЕ ВСЕ бинды СОЗДАДИМ И ПОДКЛЮЧИМ).

Дальше начинается самый сок. Устанавливаем DependencyInjection. В App.xaml.cs пишем следующее:

```
namespace app
{
    public partial class App : Application
    {
        private static IServiceProvider _service;
        public static IServiceProvider Services => _service ??= InitializeServices().BuildServiceProvider();

        private static IServiceCollection InitializeServices()
        {
            var services = new ServiceCollection();

            services.AddSingleton<IUserDialog, UserDialogServices>();
            // подключаем окно
            services.AddTransient(s =>
            {
                var model = s.GetService<MainWindowViewModel>();
                var window = new MainWindow { DataContext = model };

                return window;
            });
            // подключаем первую страницу и вьюмодел к ней
            services.AddTransient(s =>
            {
                var model = s.GetService<FirstPage>();
                var page = new FirstPage() { DataContext = model };

                return page;
            });
            services.AddTransient(s =>
            {
                var model = s.GetRequiredService<SecondPage>();
                var page = new SecondPage { DataContext = model };

                return page;
            }); 
            services.AddTransient(s =>
            {
                var model = s.GetRequiredService<ThreethPage>();
                var page = new ThreethPage { DataContext = model };

                return page;
            });

            return services;
        }

        protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnStartup(e);
            // ставим точку старта на UserDialog с методом OpenMainWindow
            Services.GetRequiredService<IUserDialog>().OpenMainWindow();
        }
    }
}
```

Что такое IUserDialog с этим OpenMainWindow? Объясняю. Тут мы фиксируем все страницы и главное окно.

Код UserDialogServices:

```
internal class UserDialogServices : IUserDialog
    {
        private readonly IServiceProvider _services;
        public UserDialogServices(IServiceProvider services)
        {
            _services = services;
        }

        private MainWindow _mainWindow;
        private FirstPage _firstPage;
        private SecondPage _secondPage;
        private ThreethPage _threethPage;

        private string _listViewPageTitle;

        public void OpenMainWindow()
        {
            if (_mainWindow is { } window) //если окно существует
            {
                window.Show();
                return; // возвращаем текущее
            }

            window = _services.GetRequiredService<MainWindow>(); // получаем главное окно из di контейнера
            window.Closed += (_, _) => _mainWindow = null;

            _mainWindow = window; // присваиваем новое созданное окно.
            window.Show();
        }
        public Page OpenFirstPage()
        {
            if (_firstPageis { } page)
            {
                return page;
            }

            page = _services.GetRequiredService<FirstPage>();

            _firstPage = page;
            return page;
        }
        public Page OpenSecondPage()
        {
            if (_secondPages { } page )
            {
                return page;
            }

            page = _services.GetRequiredService<SecondPage>();
            _secondPages = page;

            return page;
        }
        public Page OpenThreethPage()
        {
            if (_threethPage{ } page )
            {
                return page;
            }

            page = _services.GetRequiredService<ThreethPage>();
            _threethPage = page;

            return page;
        }
    }
```

Теперь при каждом открытии страницы мы будем проверять: существует ли она уже, и, если существует, то возвращаем, если нет - создаем новую.
Дальше подключаем команды во вьюмоделе главного окна. Выглядит примерно вот так:

```
internal class MainWindowViewModel : ViewModelBase
    {
        private readonly IUserDialog _userDialog;

        private Page _currentPage;
        public Page CurrentPage 
        {
            get => _currentPage;
            set => Set(ref _currentPage, value);
        }

        public MainWindowViewModel(IUserDialog userDialog) : this()
        {
            _userDialog = userDialog;
        }
        public MainWindowViewModel() { }

        #region Смена страницы

        private LambdaCommand _changePageCommand;
        public ICommand ChangePageCommand => _changePageCommand ??= new(OnChangePageCommand);
        private void OnChangePageCommand(object p)
        {
            switch ((string)p)
            {
                case "1":
                    CurrentPage = _userDialog.OpenFirstPage();
                    break;
                case "2":
                    CurrentPage = _userDialog.OpenSecondPage();
                    break;
                case "3":
                    CurrentPage = _userDialog.OpenThreethPage();
                    break;
            }
        }

        #endregion
    }
```

К команде OnChangePageCommand мы прибиндились ранее. В принимаемом параметре мы указываем какой параметр какую страницу открывает.

Проверяем и радуемся =)

Пишу подобное первый раз, извиняюсь сразу за все недочеты, я старался... Решение не самое лучшее, но используется в моём проекте. Куда лучше будет изучать MVVMCommunityTool, Catel или Prism. Способов много.

Comment: _У меня есть более элегантное решение._ - сплошной хардкод, это не круто. При добавлении нового View надо код переписывать в 3 местах, так себе элегантность. В целом идея неплохая, реализацию только отполировать.