# Можно ли как то переместить файлы app.xmal в папку и app.config?

Tags: c#, wpf

Перемещаю файл app.xmal, но в итоге элементы перестают видеть свойства прописанные в этом файле. Как правильно переместить файл app.xaml и app.config ?

Comment: а зачем его перемещать?

Comment: Ну хочется проект структурированным сделать. Что бы в каждой папке свои элементы были.

Например так:

Windows : (здесь будут создаваться окна приложения)
Pages: (страницы приложения )
Xaml: (файл App.xaml)
Config: (Файл конфигурации )

Comment: И тут мы сразу понимаем, что вы явно разрабатываете WPF проект дергая контролы из кода, не используя привязки и так далее, то есть вы живете по правилам WinForms, что в WPF плохо! А из-за этого "кривого" подхода, вы сами себе геморрой придумываете, по типу того, что в вопросе сейчас.

Comment: App.xaml и App.xaml.cs нужно перемещать вместе. Ссылки на эти файлы ищите в .cproj файле. И да, согласен с предыдущим комментарием, поизучайте что-нибудь про MVVM в WPF. Рано вы взялись порядок наводить.

Comment: Так же рекомендую для новой разработки использовать .NET 5, а не .NET Framework.

Comment: Посмотрите еще вот [это](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1266479/373567), про многостраничный интерфейс.