# Несколько файлов разметки для одного окна

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

У меня собственно имеется разметка самого окна, но так же мне нужно сделать ряд анимации при помощи разметки XAML. Поэтому хотелось бы сделать это в отдельном файле, что бы можно было легко ориентироваться в коде.
Возможно ли использовать два файла разметки для одного окна? Если да, то как это сделать? Если нет, то какие есть альтернативы?

Comment: Что для вас "файл разметки"? И что вы хотите выносить я так и не понял? Если вам надо анимации написать в отдельном файле, то делаете словарь ресурсов, подключаете его, а в нем ваши анимации по типу `<Storyboard x:Key="MyAnim" .. />`, все дальше подключаете анимацию где вам надо.

Comment: UserControl? DataTemplate? Стили в отдельном ResourceDictionary? возможностей миллион.

Comment: Можете привести пример описания анимации в ResourceDictionary? К примеру при нажатии на кнопку тексбокс сдвигается вправо на 300 пикселей.

Comment: Вы знаете как работают стили вообще в WPF? Вы знаете, что вообще такое стили? Вот вам надо, чтобы кнопка имела красный `Background`, вы пишете `<Button Background = "Red"/>`, ок, а если таких свойств много, то как тогда? Тогда вы делаете стиль `<Style x:Key ="SomeStyle" TargetType="Button"><Setter Property = "Background" Value = "Red"/></Style>` и к кнопке уже применяете его `<Button Style = "{StaticResource SomeStyle}" />`. Стили хранятся в ресурсах, это может быть ресурс контрола, а может быть ресурс всего проекта целиком.

Comment: Вот вам [простая разметка](https://pastebin.com/eVGSGtFy), где есть настроенная анимация, она в ресурсах окна, а по клику (как и просили), применяется эта анимация к нужному объекту. То есть мы как и в случае с цветом, отделили анимацию, поместив ее в ресурсы. Если нужна анимация за пределами окна, то делается словарь, просто жмется в проекте "Добавить - Словарь ресурсов" и в созданноый файл перемещаются все ресурсы. Сам файл подключается в `App.xaml` примерно [так](https://pastebin.com/6NqSRcGT), ну и словарей может быть сколько угодно и они могут быть где угодно (хоть в отдельном проекте).

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1266479/373567 - `ResourceDictionary`