# Binding не видит то, что должен выводить

Tags: c#, wpf

В xaml окне у меня есть TextBlock, который должен выводить данные с помощью Binding. Но он будто не видит, то что должен выводить. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как исправить?

```
       <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Text="Подписка:" FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="12" Foreground="White"/>
            <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding ItemModel.Name}" FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="12" Foreground="White"/>
                            <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Text="Цена:" FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="12" Foreground="White"/>
            <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding ItemModel.Price, StringFormat={}{0} руб}" FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="12" Foreground="White"/>
                            <TextBlock Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" Text="Срок подписки:" FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="12" Foreground="White"/>
            <TextBlock Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding ItemModel.Time, StringFormat={}{0} Месяц}" FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="12" Foreground="White"/>
                            <TextBlock Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="0" Text="Тема:" FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="12" Foreground="White"/>
            <TextBlock Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding ItemModel.Topic}" FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="12" Foreground="White"/>
                            <TextBlock Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="0" Text="Автор:" FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="12" Foreground="White"/>
            <TextBlock Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding ItemModel.Author}" FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="12" Foreground="White"/>
```

ItemModel берёт всё из базы данных.

```
 public int id { get; set; }

        private string name, topic, author;
        private int price, time;

        public string Name
        {
            get { return name; }
            set { name = value; }
        }

        public int Price
        {
            get { return price; }
            set { price = value; }
        }

        public int Time
        {
            get { return time; }
            set { time = value; }
        }

        public string Topic
        {
            get { return topic; }
            set { topic = value; }
        }
        public string Author
        {
            get { return author; }
            set { author = value; }
        }

        public ItemModel() { }

        public ItemModel(string name, int price, int time, string topic, string author)
        {
            this.name = name;
            this.price = price;
            this.time = time;
            this.topic = topic;
            this.author = author;
        }
```

Comment: Недостаточно информации, чтобы понять, в чем проблема. `DataContext` настроен? Почему у вас модель исполняет роль вью-модели? Если данные меняются после создания экземпляра модели, то нужно реализовать `INotifyPropertyChanged`, чтобы интерфейс увидел эти изменения. Если данные не меняются, то зачем реализованы сеттеры в свойствах?

Comment: Да, данные меняются, у меня есть добавление и удаление подписок. Также DataContext реализован. Получается нужно реализовать INotifyPropertyChanged, чтобы заработало?

Comment: Что у вас заданно в `DataContext`? Есть ли в том классе публичное свойство с типом `ItemModel` и аналогичным названием (аля `public ItemModel ItemModel { get;}`)?

Comment: Первоначально у меня в DataContext загоняется  `DataContext="{Binding Source={x:Static local:Samples.SamplePost}}"` А в Samples хранится первоначальная информация                    
`public static ItemModel SamplePost =>
            new ItemModel()
            {
                Name = "Газета Правда",
                Price = 1000,
                Time = 1,
                Topic = "Новости",
                Author = "Россия"
            };`

Comment: Почему у вас это все `static`? Статику не место в проекте! Ну и также посмотрите внимательно на свой код, повторю вопрос "У вас есть в `SamplePost` публичное свойство с типом `ItemModel` и аналогичным именем?" Я этого не вижу, вижу, что `SamplePost` и есть `ItemModel`, тогда почему привязка у вас идет так `ItemModel.Name`, а не так `Name`?

Comment: ItemModel.Name это были старые пробы, а так у меня было без ItemModel, но не работало. И подскажите, что использовать вместо static?

Comment: @Dr.Crow не совсем в тему, но вот рабочий пример https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1266479/373567

Comment: `но не работало` - это не объяснение. Добавляйте в вопрос все необходимое, все ваши попытки, показывайте как задаете `DataContext`, показывайте как инициализируете все типы, показывайте привязки. `что использовать вместо static` - ничего? Статик либо есть, либо его нету, а быть его у вас не должно!

Comment: Всё заработало! После того, как убрал ItemModel стало выдавать ошибку XDG0008, я ткнул на неё и нашёл решение, а именно - удаление папки .vs и пересборка. Теперь всё выводится, спасибо за помощь! Остаётся теперь добавление правильно сделать, чтобы не только Sample показывался, но и то, что добавил.