# Открытие новых окон в WPF MVVM (концептуальный вопрос)

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Допустим есть `Window1`, на нем есть `Button`. По нажатию на `Button` должно открываться новое окно `Window2`. Где это лучше сделать? Внутри `Window1.xaml.cs`(т.е добавить обработчик события), или лучше сделать для этого свойство `ICommand` в соответствующей `ViewModel`?

Первый вариант вроде неплохо смотрится, однако MVVM существует чтобы отделить логику от представления, но в этом варианте необходимо будет написать логику открытия окна внутри `View`.

Второй вариант тоже должен нарушать MVVM, ведь мы связываем `ViewModel` и `View`.

Есть ли какой-то "правильный" с точки зрения концепции MVVM способ открытия окон? Слышал про паттерн Messenger, но то ли это?

Comment: С точки зрения MVVM окон вообще не существует. А потому приходится изобретать свое разной степени удобства. И все способы правильные, если выполняется одно условие - вьюмодель не имеет прямой зависимости на окна.

Comment: Мы у себя вообще не делаем новых окон. А просто на передний план выводим слой, напоминающий окно. Пишем UserControl с крестиком закрытия и его и отображаем, управляя свойством Visibility, например.

Comment: Прилинковал дубликат, и еще [сюда](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1266479/373567) загляние.

Comment: @aepot хорошо, спасибо