# MVVM как создать экземпляр ViewModel

Tags: c#, wpf, классы, mvvm, view

У меня есть страница (ProfilePage) и её ViewModel (Page1ViewModel).

С первого экземпляра страницы ProfilePage есть возможность перехода на второй экземпляр страницы ProfilePage

```
_pageService.ChangePage(new ProfilePage());
await _messageBus.SendTo<Page1ViewModel>(new TextMessage(ID.ToString()));
```

Если оставить как сейчас, то есть создавать экземпляр Page и передать в Page1ViewModel id выбранного пользователя, то создается новая страница с новым пользователем, но при нажатии кнопки back в навигации frame, старая страница так же с новым id.

Я подумал, что логично было бы, бы если каждая страница имела свой экземпляр Page1ViewModel, и при выборе на первой странице пользователя, создавалась страница со своим VM, и передать ID в новый VM

Как это реализовывается?

**ProfilePage XAML**

```
<Page
      xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
      xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
      xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
      xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
      xmlns:views="clr-namespace:SystemBackdropTypes.Enums"
      xmlns:local="clr-namespace:SystemBackdropTypes"
      DataContext="{Binding Page1ViewModel, Source={StaticResource ViewModelLocator}}" x:Class="SystemBackdropTypes.ProfilePage"
      mc:Ignorable="d"
      d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800"
      Title="{Binding CurrentID}" xmlns:i="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity">

    <Page.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="TextBlock" x:Key="TextBlockDescription">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="Text" Value="">
                    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
                </Trigger>
                <Trigger Property="Text" Value="{x:Null}">
                    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Page.Resources>

    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="Loaded">
            <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding LoadedCommand}" />
        </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>

    <Grid>
        <Grid ShowGridLines="True">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition  MinHeight="150" />
                <RowDefinition  MinHeight="200" Height="*"/>
                <RowDefinition  MinHeight="170"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="72" MinWidth="72"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="240*" MinWidth="258" MaxWidth="480"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="121"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="337"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Border CornerRadius="5" Opacity="40" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Margin="10" Background="#FF383838" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                <Grid>
                    <Image x:Name="image" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="106" Margin="10" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="106" Source="{Binding avatar}" Stretch="UniformToFill"/>
                    <DockPanel Margin="130,0,0,0" d:Background="Red" VerticalAlignment="Top" >
                        <TextBlock TextWrapping="WrapWithOverflow" DockPanel.Dock="Top" Foreground="White" FontSize="20"><Run d:Text="Имя}" Text="{Binding first_name}"/><Run Text=" "/><Run d:Text="Фамилия" Text="{Binding last_name}"/></TextBlock>
                        <TextBlock x:Name="status" DockPanel.Dock="Top" TextWrapping="Wrap" d:Text="Статус" Foreground="White" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0" Text="{Binding status}"/>
                    </DockPanel>
                </Grid>
            </Border>

            <Border CornerRadius="5" Opacity="40" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Margin="10" Background="#FF383838" VerticalAlignment="Top">
                <Grid>
                    <DockPanel d:Background="Red">
                        <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource TextBlockDescription}" Margin="10,5,10,5" DockPanel.Dock="Top" TextWrapping="Wrap" d:Text="29 подписчиков" Foreground="White" FontSize="15" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="Auto" Text="{Binding followers_count}"/>
                        <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource TextBlockDescription}" Margin="10,5,10,5" DockPanel.Dock="Top" TextWrapping="Wrap" d:Text="Город: " Foreground="White" FontSize="15" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="Auto" Text="{Binding home_town}"/>
                        <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource TextBlockDescription}" Margin="10,5,10,5" DockPanel.Dock="Top" TextWrapping="Wrap" d:Text="Работает в: " Foreground="White" FontSize="15" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="Auto" Text="{Binding Occupations}"/>
                        <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource TextBlockDescription}" Margin="10,5,10,5" DockPanel.Dock="Top" TextWrapping="Wrap" d:Text="Сайт" Foreground="White" FontSize="15" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="Auto" Text="{Binding site}"/>
                        <Button DockPanel.Dock="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Content="Подробная информация" Command="{Binding AddPanel}"/>
                    </DockPanel>
                </Grid>
            </Border>

            <Grid Grid.Column="1" Margin="10" Grid.Row="2" Background="#FF383838" VerticalAlignment="Top">
                <StackPanel>
                    <Label Content="Друзья" Margin="10" Foreground="White" FontSize="20"/>
                    <ListBox Margin="10" ItemsSource="{Binding Friends}" SelectedValue="{Binding SelectedFriendId}" SelectedValuePath="IdFriend">
                        <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
                            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        </ListBox.ItemsPanel>

                        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <Grid VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
                                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                        <RowDefinition Height="50"></RowDefinition>
                                        <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
                                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <Image Grid.Row="0" Source="{Binding AvatarFriend}"/>
                                    <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Text="{Binding NameFriend}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                                </Grid>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    </ListBox>
                </StackPanel>
            </Grid>
        </Grid>

    </Grid>
</Page>
```

**ProfilePage**

```
namespace SystemBackdropTypes.ViewModels
{
    public class Page1ViewModel : BindableBase
    {
        private readonly PageService _pageService;
        private readonly ControlService _controlService;
        private readonly EventBus _eventBus;
        private readonly MessageBus _messageBus;



        public string CurrentID { get; set; } // ID текущего пользователя
        public string? LogText { get; set; }

        #region Первая панель | Текущий пользователь
        public string? first_name { get; set; }
        public string? last_name { get; set; }
        public string? status { get; set; }
        public string avatar { get; set; } = "https://vk.com/images/camera_200.png";
        #endregion

        #region Вторая панель | Описание пользователя
        public string? home_town { get; set; } // Родной город
        public string? followers_count { get; set; } // Подписчики
        public string? Occupations { get; private set; }// Род деятельности
        public string? site { get; private set; } // Сайт
        #endregion

        #region Третья панель | Друзья
        private int _selectedFriendId;
        public IEnumerable<Friend>? Friends { get; private set; }
        #endregion

        public Page1ViewModel(PageService pageService, ControlService controlService, EventBus eventBus, MessageBus messageBus, int id = 0)
        {

            PanelVMs = new ObservableCollection<PanelViewModel>();


            Debug.WriteLine(Properties.Settings.Default.token);

            _pageService = pageService;
            _controlService = controlService;
            _eventBus = eventBus;
            _messageBus = messageBus;

            _controlService.OnUserControlChanged += (usercontrol) => Change(usercontrol);

            _messageBus.Receive<TextMessage>(this, async message =>
            {
                //MessageBox.Show("Открыл профиль " + message.Text);
                CurrentID = message.Text;
            });
        }

        private void Change(System.Windows.Controls.UserControl usercontrol)
        {
            CurrentPage = usercontrol;
        }

        public async void OpenProfile(int ID)
        {


            await _eventBus.Publish(new LeaveFromFirstPageEvent());
            //Loaded();
            _pageService.ChangePage(new ProfilePage());
            await _messageBus.SendTo<Page1ViewModel>(new TextMessage(ID.ToString()));

            //MessageBox.Show(CurrentID.ToString());

        }

        public ICommand SendLog => new AsyncCommand(async () =>
        {
            await _messageBus.SendTo<LogPageViewModel>(new TextMessage(LogText.ToString()));
            //await _messageBus.SendTo<object>(new TextMessage(LogText));

        });



        public void Loaded()
        {
            avatar = "https://imgur.com/pKopwXp"; // загрузка
            if (CurrentID == null)
            {
                //MessageBox.Show("Моя старница");
                GetProfileInfo();
                CurrentID = "0";
            }
            else
            {
                
                UsersGet();
            }

            GetFindFriends();
        }

        private async void GetFindFriends()
        {
            
            var data = await Utility.FetchFriendsInfo(CurrentID, "5");
            Friends = new ObservableCollection<Friend>();
            foreach (var friend in data.response.items)
            {
                Friends = Friends.Concat
                      (new[] {
                          new Friend {IdFriend = friend.id, NameFriend = friend.first_name, AvatarFriend = friend.photo_100},
                      });
            }

        }

        public async void GetProfileInfo()
        {
            var data = await Utility.GetProfileInfo();
            await _messageBus.SendTo<MainViewModel>(new TextMessage(data.ToString()));
            first_name = data.response.first_name;
            last_name = data.response.last_name;
            avatar = data.response.photo_200;
            home_town = "Город: " + data.response.home_town;
            status = data.response.status == null ? "" : data.response.status;
        }

        private dynamic ProfileInfo {get; set;}
        public async void UsersGet()
        {
            var data = await Utility.UsersGet(CurrentID);
            await _messageBus.SendTo<MainViewModel>(new TextMessage(data.ToString()));
            ProfileInfo = data;
            first_name = data.response[0].first_name;
            last_name = data.response[0].last_name;
            avatar = data.response[0].photo_100;
            home_town = "Город: " + data.response[0].home_town;
            status = data.response[0].status == null ? "" : data.response[0].status;
            followers_count = data.response[0].followers_count + " подписчиков";
            Occupations = data["response"][0]["occupation"]["name"];
            site = data["response"][0]["site"];
        }

        private ObservableCollection<PanelViewModel> _panelVMs;
        public ObservableCollection<PanelViewModel> PanelVMs
        {
            get { return _panelVMs; }
            set { SetProperty(ref _panelVMs, value, () => PanelVMs); }
        }
        private DelegateCommand _AddPanel;
        public DelegateCommand AddPanel
        {
            get { return _AddPanel ?? (_AddPanel = new DelegateCommand(AddPanelExecute)); }
        }
        private async void AddPanelExecute()
        {
            //PanelVMs.Add(new PanelViewModel());
            //Panel b = new Panel();
            //CurrentPage = b;

            _controlService.ChangeUserControl(new Panel());
            await _messageBus.SendTo<PanelViewModel>(new TextMessage(ProfileInfo.ToString()));
        }

        #region Выбор id друга
        public int SelectedFriendId
        {
            get { return _selectedFriendId; }
            set
            {
                if (value != _selectedFriendId)
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine(string.Format("setting friend to: {0}", value));
                    OpenProfile(value);
                    _selectedFriendId = value;
                }
            }
        }
        #endregion

        /*public int SelectedOccupationId
        {
            get { return _selectedOccupationId; }
            set
            {
                if (value != _selectedOccupationId)
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine(string.Format("Selected Occupation: {0}", value));
                    _selectedOccupationId = value;
                }
            }
        }*/

        private DelegateCommand loadedCommand;
        public ICommand LoadedCommand => loadedCommand ??= new DelegateCommand(Loaded);

        private object currentPage;

        public object CurrentPage { get => currentPage; set => SetValue(ref currentPage, value); }
    }

    public class Friend
    {
        public int IdFriend { get; set; }
        public string AvatarFriend { get; set; }
        public string NameFriend { get; set; }
    }

    /*public class Occupation
    {
        public int IdOccupation { get; set; }
        public string type { get; set; }
        public string NameOccupation { get; set; }
    }*/
}
```

**PageService**

```
public class PageService
    {
        public event Action<Page, string> OnPageChanged;

        public void ChangePage(Page page, string message = "")
        {
            OnPageChanged?.Invoke(page, message);
        }
    }
```

**MainViewModel**

```
public Page PageSource { get; set; }
public MainViewModel(PageService pageService, MessageBus messageBus)
{
        _pageService = pageService;
        _messageBus = messageBus;

        _pageService.OnPageChanged += (page, message) => Change(page, message);
        _pageService.ChangePage(new LoginPage());
            

        _messageBus.Receive<TextMessage>(this, async message =>
        {
            logtext = message.Text;
                
        });
}
 public void Change(Page page, string message)
 {
        PageSource = page;
}
```

Comment: Ничего непонятно, но очень интересно. Вам уже писали здесь, что Frame+Page в WPF - неудачное решение. Зря игнорируете. А чтобы разобраться с вашей ситуацией, нужен минимальный воспроизводимый пример, потому что инструменты для реализации задачи, вы выбрали мягко говоря непопулярные.

Comment: Если уж хочется приложение с модной навигацией, пишите сразу под Windows App SDK, а не WPF. Там конечно своих приколов достаточно, но навигация в порядке, и события есть, по которым видно, когда сраница пришла на экран, и когда ушла. И NavigationView толковый.

Comment: Честно, отвечать вообще не хочется, ибо я вам уже много раз писал, что вы делаете ерунду: 1. `Page` и `Frame` - это ИМХО, нарушение MVVM, они не предназначены для него от слова совсем! 2. View слой не должен отвечать за VM, а значит не должно быть всяких `DataContext="{Binding Page1ViewModel, Source={StaticResource ViewModelLocator}}"` в XAML. 3. Статика ЗЛО, а у вас весь `ViewModelLocator` на нем... Не захотели, ну вот, страдайте теперь, вас предупреждали, раз не хотите слушать более опытных людей. А у меня нет желания разбирать этот костыль и повторять все в сотый раз, извините.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ а можно пример проекта, например с GitHub? Я просто не совсем понимаю, я на WPF даже и месяц на работал. Я делал по [этому примеру](https://github.com/BashkaMen/WpfExample)

Comment: @Mr.Dandomi Я вам очень сильно советую научиться выбирать правильных учителей, правильный материал, а не первого попавшегося парня с ютуба, который сам толком не знает, что делает, но учит людей. Научитесь сами анализировать, сами воспринимать материал, искать его на англоязычных ресурсах и т.д. Я вам уже говорил: "забудьте про фреймворки, познайте базу WPF, а затем облегчайте себе жизнь всем сторонним", вы же меня не послушали. Ну а пример, вам уже кидали пример, смотрите предыдущие ваши вопросы.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ я решил последовать Вашему совету. Я [воспользовался примером](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1266044/%d0%9d%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%b3%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%b2-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d1%81-%d1%87%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b9-%d1%81%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b9-view/1266479#1266479) который мне кидали. Но View1 и View2 ошибка, которую мне не удалось исправить. [Скрин](https://imgur.com/a/NXl54qJ)

Comment: @Mr.Dandomi Проект пересоберите, WPF обновляет все данные для XAML только после успешной сборки! Ключевое слово "успешной", если есть еще ошибки, которые мешают сборке, устраните их.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ вот и в этом проблема. Я был удивлён, но именно эти ошибки мешают сборки. Больше ошибок нет

Comment: @Mr.Dandomi ну тут уж извините, без самодостаточного примера, я вам не скажу, где у вас проблема. У вас, по сути, несколько вариантов: 1. Есть еще ошибка, помимо XAML привязок. 2. Проект не пересобрали. 3. `namespace` указанного класса отличается от того, что вы пишете в XAML. Вот собственно и проверяйте все это.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ так и не смог найти причину. [Не поможете?](https://dropmefiles.com/qICFM)

Comment: @Mr.Dandomi Скачал, чуть подправил namespace в xaml (`clr-namespace:WpfMVVMCore.ViewModels;assembly=WpfMVVMCore`, тут `;assembly=WpfMVVMCore` лишнее), очистил, пересобрал. Вроде проблем нет...

Comment: Да, спасибо, получилось (хотя ранее я удалял `;assembly=WpfMVVMCore`, и у меня всё равно не работало, ну да ладно). Это несколько сложная реализация MVVM для меня. Как тут можно создавать окна профиля с разным id и реализовать кнопку back page?