# Свойство Template для Window

Tags: c#, wpf

Задача моя была проста - создать оформление для `Window` через `Style`, учитывая контент окна.

**Суть проблемы**: Добавление `Setter Property="Template"` не даёт приложению запуститься, а так как WPF не выводит исключения, в чём проблема - не ясно.

**Проблема точно не в**: ссылках на классы/xaml, подключении файлов ( так как без `Setter Property="Template"` всё запускается как необходимо ).

AuthorizationView.xaml:

```
<Window 
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    x:Class="NC.view.AuthorizationView"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Style="{ StaticResource SpaceView }"
    Width="350" Height="450"
>
    <Grid>
        <TextBlock>TEST</TextBlock>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

SpaceView.xaml:

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <Style
        BasedOn="{ StaticResource { x:Type Window } }"
        TargetType="Window"
        x:Key="SpaceView"
    >
        <Setter 
            Property="WindowStyle"
            Value="None"
        />
        <Setter
            Property="ResizeMode"
            Value="NoResize"
        />
        
        <Setter 
            Property="AllowsTransparency"
            Value="True"
        />
        <Setter 
            Property="Background"
            Value="Transparent"
        />
        
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="Window">
                    <Border
                        Background="{ StaticResource BaseColor }"
                        CornerRadius="{ StaticResource BorderRadius }"
                    >
                        <ContentPresenter/>
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

Ожидается увидеть как "результат":

```
<Window 
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    x:Class="NC.view.AuthorizationView"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    WindowStyle="None"
    ResizeMode="NoResize"
    AllowsTransparency="True"
    Background="Transparent"
    Width="350" Height="450"
>
    <Border
        Background="{ StaticResource BaseColor }"
        CornerRadius="{ StaticResource BorderRadius }"
    >
        <Grid>
            <TextBlock>TEST</TextBlock>
        </Grid>
    </Border>
</Window>
```

Comment: Быть может вы словарь забыли подключить, где эти стили https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1266479/373567

Comment: `так как WPF не выводит исключения` - с чего это вдруг. Запускаете студию, запускаете там проект через отладку и получаете все ошибки. `Ожидается увидеть как "результат":` - вот это я не понял к чему. Ну а так, скопировал ваш стиль, вставил его в `App.xaml`, поменял там `BaseColor` и `BorderRadius` (ибо у вас их нету), скопировал стиль окна, запустил все [без проблем](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nSLd4.png). Так что, **не воспроизводится**, стоит вам заняться отладкой для начала, узнать, что конкретно не нравиться именно в вашем проекте (к примеру, нет `BaseColor`). P.S. Ужасное форматирование!

Comment: @aepot, ошибка действительно оказалась в словарях, но не отсутствия их подключения, а порядке, благодарю за наводку)

Comment: @EvgeniyZ, благодарю за ответ, в Debug режиме действительно пишутся исключения, не знал. 

С проблемой разобрался, оказалось порядок подключения словарей влияет, с "BaseColor" был в самом низу ( ох, жалко потраченного дня из-за простого порядка стилей... ).

Отправьте полноценный ответ, отмечу решением, как станет доступно :)

Comment: Я ответ оформлять не буду по одной простой причине - считаю это "опечаткой", ибо проблема легко ловится отладкой, а значит и ценности в ответе для сообщества, по сути, нет (мое ИМХО). Ну а так, можете написать ответ самостоятельно.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Решение**: Проблема оказалась в порядке подключения `ResourceDictionary` в `Application.Resources`. Имеющийся в `SpaceView` статический ресурс `BaseColor` подключался позднее, чем использовался.

**Примечание для пользователей JetBrains Rider**: Пробрасываемые исключения отображаются в `Debug mode` (Shift + F9), в отличии от `Run mode` (Shift + F10).