# Как в frame перейти на другой frame?

Tags: c#, wpf

У меня есть главное окно.

**Окно авторизации** - после успешной авторизации отображается другое окно (**StartSchoolboy**)

В окне **StartSchoolboy** поумолчанию отображается frame с кнопками.

Почему по нажатии кнопки я не могу перейти в другой Frame ?

Кнопка находится в Frame (который отображён поумолчанию)

```
 private void btnBookMe_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
 {
    
        StartSchoolboy startSchoolboy = new StartSchoolboy();
                
        startSchoolboy.startFrame.Navigate(new MyBookPage());

        //Меняет стиль кнопок у окна  StartSchoolboy
        ButtonStyles.StyleButton(startSchoolboy.btnMyBooks, startSchoolboy.btnMain,
        startSchoolboy.btnBooks, startSchoolboy.btnExitZapic);
 }
```

Comment: Типичная ошибка, где вместо того, чтоб использовать уже проинициализированный объект, создается непойми зачем новый. Передавайте через конструктор экземпляр нужного объекта и работайте с его ссылкой, а не делайте `new StartSchoolboy()`. Касательно всего кода и подхода в целом, то он ужасен. В WPF вся суть в привязках и XAML разметке, ну а если вы это все не используете, делаете контролы через код, меняете через код стили, храните данные в контролах, то зачем тогда вам WPF? Вон WinForms, там такое в неком виде актуально, но WPF, это совсем другое, тут так делать плохо.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1266479/373567