# Выполнение действия в момент отображении страницы C# WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

У меня есть страница Page1.xaml и файл Page1.xaml.cs
Внутри находится конструктор страницы:

```
public Page1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}
```

А также условный метод:

```
private void Method1()
{
    ...
}
```

Я хочу, чтобы Method1() выполнился сразу после того как консруктор Page1() завершит свою работу и будет отображена страница Page1. Так же как если бы пользователь нажал на специальную кнопку, но не дожидаясь этого, а сразу в момент отображения страницы.
Запускать метод внутри конструктора Page() не вариант, так как Method1() должен асинхронно выполнить распаковку большого архива, а страница в это время должна оторажать прогресс распаковки.

**Как я могу вызвать асинхронный метод Method1() в момент отображения страницы Page1?**

Comment: Я знаю, что в Android есть метод onCreate() на такие случаи. В WPF есть нечто подобное?

Comment: Выбирайте событие Initialized или Loaded

Comment: Page в WPF - не очень эффективное решение, обработчики событий тоже не популярны. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1266479/373567

Comment: @vitidev спасибо за наводку, нашёл нужное событие.

Comment: @aepot я новичок в WPF, переписывать приложение уже не хочу, но на будущее сохраню, спасибо.

Comment: В WPF идет голый MVVM, при чем View полностью помещается в XAML. В результате в C# остается только бизнес-логика.