# Переход с одной страницы на другую

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Есть фрейм. В нём уже задана страница. Но на этой странице есть кнопка, я хочу чтобы при нажатии на неё страница менялась. Но как это сделать соблюдая MVVM паттерн?

Comment: Дубликат: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25845689/opening-new-window-in-mvvm-wpf

Comment: @Frehzy А разве дубликат не должен быть на русском?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1266479/373567

Comment: @LaukhinAndrey Хорошо, учту. Думал, что точь-в-точь похожие вопросы на англоязычной части форума тоже учитываются