# Как генерировать в фоне компонент WPF с последующим сохранением в PNG

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, png

Никак не могу отрисовать в фоне визуальное дерево WPF (приходится делать вьюшки, с последующим их отражением) - это не удобно, видно как окно моментально появляется и исчезает.

```
        private static byte[] GetPNG<T>(INotifyPropertyChanged viewModel)
            where T : Window, new()
        {
            var wnd = new T()
            {
                DataContext = viewModel
            };
            wnd.Show();

            var content = (FrameworkElement)wnd.Content;

            var rtb = new RenderTargetBitmap((int)content.ActualWidth, (int)content.ActualHeight, 96d, 96d, PixelFormats.Default);
            rtb.Render(content);

            BitmapEncoder pngEncoder = new PngBitmapEncoder();
            pngEncoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(rtb));

            using var ms = new MemoryStream();

            pngEncoder.Save(ms);

            wnd.Close();

            return ms.ToArray();
        }
```

На данный момент только так...

Может у кого-нибудь есть решение - или знает способ отрисовки в памяти без помещения компонента в визуальное дерево?

Comment: Можете объяснить суть, вы скриншот окна таким образом рисуете чтоли? Или как это понимать? Что вообще происходит, зачем это делать? Возмите GDI+ (`System.Drawing`), нарисуйте на битмапе все что хотите, и готово. Тоже своего рода вьюха. А так, задайте окну координаты за рамками монитора, например -10000, -10000, выключите ему отображение в таскбаре и негативный эффект от всплывающего окна не будет вас беспокоить.

Comment: Кстати, если вьюхи хранить [в шаблонах в ресурсах](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1266479/373567), а не в окнах, то у этого метода можно будет избавиться от обобщения. Просто использовать какое-то одно специальное окно для этого. Это на случай, если вам нужна скорость, то можно будет окно-синглтон не пересоздавать, а скрывать/показывать, подменяя ему вьюмодель.

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/graphics-multimedia/how-to-encode-a-visual-to-an-image-file в документации кстати без окна процесс делается. А вот [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20721353/12888024) обратите внимание на фокус в arrange/measure.

Comment: Основная задача отрисовать в фоне элемент интерфейса собранного в XAML, я так не умею
Графические примитивы рисовать могу в GDI+, шейдеры писать могу, и все другое.
Нужно именно XAML (в моем случае, пробежаться по визуальному дереву WPF).
Вот не могу заставить (вернее не знаю как):
1. задать layout (для задания ширины и автоматического расчета высоты, которая может быть разной);
2. выполнить updatelayout элемента который не помещен в отображаемое визуальное дерево.
Все мои фоновые варианты не имеют размера Size(0,0) и соответственно png черная

Comment: Воспроизводимый пример бы получить. Тема не популярная, на уровне кода мало что можно придумать. Надо трогать и играться.

Comment: Увы весь проект не могу скинуть. Вечером, если будет время, шаблон накидаю.

Comment: Так проект никто и не просит, мало того, он и не нужен. Нужен минимальный воспроизводимый пример, где работает то что вам нужно. Чтобы проблема с размерами контролов там воспроизводилась так же как в вашем основном проекте