# Как сменить View в Avalonia NVVM?

Tags: c#, avalonia

Я сделал фронт для нескольких видов и теперь разбираюсь как их сменять из кода, например после инициализации приложения открывать главное окно или окно для регистрации(в одном окне, конечно, создание нового окна не подойдет). Я нашел что-то про ViewLocator в доках, ноя не понимаю как мне им пользоваться. Может есть какой-нибудь пример кода с переключением видов или какой-то конкретный метод?

Comment: Что такое NVVM?

Comment: В WPF я делал вот так https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1266479/373567