# Я хочу динамически создать разметку для страниц, используя MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

На форме есть TabControl, элементы которого берутся из ViewModel, на каждой вкладке TabControl расположен ScrollViewer внутри которого несколько страниц Page.
Я хочу иметь возможность произвольно распологать страницы на вкладке, описывая их расположение во ViewModel.
Ширина и высота страниц фиксированная.
Я сделал реализацию, которая позволяет решать эту задачу, если нужно расположить страницы в несоклько колонок, или несоклько рядов, с несколькими страницами в колонке или в ряду.
Но возникла необходимость сделать такой макет как на картике, и нужно разбить левую колонку еще на две колонки, а в будущем может придется еще более мелкое разбиение.
Кто-нибудь знает решение получше?

```
<TabControl Height="{Binding ElementName=helperTabControlHeight, Path=ActualHeight}" ItemsSource="{Binding TabControlItems}">
<TabControl.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Header}"/>
    </DataTemplate>
</TabControl.ItemTemplate>
<TabControl.ContentTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <ScrollViewer Height="auto" Width="auto" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
            <StackPanel>
                <!-- Ряды со страницами -->
                <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding HorizontalStackPanels}">
                    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
                        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding PageItems}">
                                <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
                                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                                <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate>
                                        <Frame Content="{Binding Page}" NavigationUIVisibility="Hidden"/>
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                            </ItemsControl>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                </ItemsControl>
                <!-- /Ряды со страницами -->
                <!-- Колонки со страницами -->
                <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding VerticalStackPanels}">
                    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
                        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding PageItems}">
                                <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical"/>
                                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                                <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate>
                                        <Frame Content="{Binding Page}" NavigationUIVisibility="Hidden"/>
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                            </ItemsControl>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                </ItemsControl>
                <!-- /Колонки со страницами -->
            </StackPanel>
        </ScrollViewer>
    </DataTemplate>
</TabControl.ContentTemplate>
```

```
private void CreateTabControlItems()
{
    TabControlItem tabControlItem = new TabControlItem { Header = "Вкладка 1", HorizontalStackPanels = new List<MyStackPanel>(), VerticalStackPanels = new List<MyStackPanel>() };
    tabControlItem.VerticalStackPanels.Add(new MyStackPanel { PageItems = new List<PageItem>() { new PageItem { Page = new Views.Pages.Page1() } } });
    tabControlItem.VerticalStackPanels.Add(new MyStackPanel { PageItems = new List<PageItem>() { new PageItem { Page = new Views.Pages.Page2() }, new PageItem { Page = new Views.Pages.Page3() } } });
    TabControlItems.Add(tabControlItem);
}
public class TabControlItem
{
    public string Header { get; set; } //заголовок вкладки
    public List<MyStackPanel> HorizontalStackPanels { get; set; } //ряды со страницами
    public List<MyStackPanel> VerticalStackPanels { get; set; } //колонки со страницами. Предполагается использовать либо HorizontalStackPanels либо VerticalStackPanels, в зависимости от того как лучше скомпоновать страницы
}
public class MyStackPanel
{
    public List<PageItem> PageItems { get; set; } //страницы, расположенные в один ряд или в одну колонку
}
public class PageItem
{
    public Page Page { get; set; }
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Насколько я понял, вы имеете ввиду responsive ui. Советую посмотреть https://youtu.be/9mMD2F3HiIM https://youtu.be/EfXz4C5cSVI эти видео. В них показано, как создать такой ui, который бы изменялся под размеры формы

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1266479/373567 выбросить Frame/Page и верстать на чистых шаблонах советую. `Ширина и высота страниц фиксированная` - а это плохой знак. Хардкода в верстке не должно быть.