# c# WPF MVVM Общий источник для нескольких разных ViewModel

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

У меня имеется ItemsControl

```xml
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding ItemsCollection}"> <!-- если общий источник данных -->
   <ItemsControl.Resources>
      <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:ViewModel_1}">
         <!--1-ый контрол -->
      </DataTemplate>
      <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:ViewModel_2}">
         <!--2-ой контрол -->
      </DataTemplate>
      <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:ViewModel_3}">
         <!--3-ий контрол -->
      </DataTemplate>
   </ItemsControl.Resources>
</ItemsControl>
```

MainViewModel которая должна хранить коллекцию контролов

```
class MainViewModel : ViewModel
    {
        public ObservableCollection<ViewModel_1> ItemsCollection_1 { get; set; }
        public ObservableCollection<ViewModel_2> ItemsCollection_2 { get; set; }
        public ObservableCollection<ViewModel_3> ItemsCollection_3 { get; set; }

        public MainViewModel()
        {
            ItemsCollection_1 = new ObservableCollection<ViewModel_1>();
            ItemsCollection_2 = new ObservableCollection<ViewModel_2>();
            ItemsCollection_3 = new ObservableCollection<ViewModel_3>();
        }

    }
```

Как сделать, чтобы 3 разные ViewModel можно было хранить в одной коллекции, или привязать к ItemsControl 3 источника данных

Comment: Делаете интерфейс, ну или абстрактный класс (если есть общая логика), делаете коллекцию этих интерфейсов, каждый тип наследуете от интерфейса, ну и заполняете коллекцию. Как бы, простое наследование...

Comment: наследование же https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1266479/373567