# Всем привет,есть проблема в понимании WinForms.(C#)

Tags: c#, winforms

А именно в переходах между формами,получается так,что при скрытии формы.У меня,как бы иконка в панеле задач перемещается туда-сюда при быстром нажатии по кнопкам,и это как бы не эстетично,а сама форма начинает flick'ать(то есть исчезает-появляется,как бы с наложением).Мб я что-то делаю не так.Это мой первый вопрос на stack,раньше прогал на Python(kivy).Там использовал ScreenManager(и он в этом плане стабилен,то есть без flick'ов и появлений в панеле задач иконка(она всегда находится в одном месте).

```
Form form2 = new Form2(); 
this.Hide(); 
form2.Show();
```

То же самое и для Формы 2.Помогите пожалуйста разобраться.Хотелось бы по-стабильнее без flick'ов,ответов на stack'е я не нашёл.

Comment: Форма же -то по сути окно. Если вы делаете переход между формами, то вы одно окно закрываете, а другое открываете. Вот и моргает все

Comment: а есть другие способы реализации перехода?

Comment: Не закрывать главное окно, использовать дочерние MDI окна, как в Visual Studio или фотошопе, либо менять панели с контролами внутри одного окна. Либо вообще взять WPF и устроить [что-то такое](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1266479/373567). Либо использовать `ShowDialog()` и вообще не прятать главную форму, а дочерней задать `ShowInTaskBar = false`. Зависит от того, что именно хотите.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ,WPF рассмотрю как вариант,он по дизайну похож на kivy,html.Всего хорошего вам:)

Comment: @MagistrShow все верно, XAML немного похож на HTML, но только немного. Если вдруг возметесь за WPF, обязательно подробно изучите 2 вещи - MVVM и привязки данных. Без этих знаний будет сильно тяжелее, чем в Winforms, а если изучите - сильно проще.