# Как сделать многофайловый проект WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf

у меня вопрос, каким образом должна выполяться логика в WPF с многофайловым проектом? У меня есть задание - написать калькулятор используя заданные интерфейсы. Например есть интерфейс ICalculatorView:

```
interface ICalculatorView
{
    /**
    * Отображает результат вычисления
    */
    void PrintResult(double result);

    /**
     * Показывает ошибку, например деление на 0, пустые аргументы и прочее
     */
    void DisplayError(string message);

    /**
     * Возвращает значение, введенное в поле первого аргументы
     */
    string GetFirstArgumentAsString();

    /**
     * Возвращает значение, введенное в поле второго аргументы
     */
    string GetSecondArgumentAsString();
}
```

И вот каким образом я получу значение из TextBox с помощью GetFirstArgumentAsString(), если доступ к TextBox у меня есть только в MainWindow.xaml.cs (кстати почему? я же хочу использовать введенные данные пользователем и в других классах). Или `PrintResult(double result)`, я же могу написать `TextBox = (string)result;` или что-то подобное только в MainWindow.xaml.cs. Так каким образом я могу через метод PrintResult вывести в нужный мне TextBox значение?

Comment: Разделение интерфейса окна и данных происходит через MVVM модель в WPF. Через контекст данных DataContext и привязку данных Binding можно привязать к окну другой класс и данные из него.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1266479/373567