# Как сделать правильную авторизацию для админа и продавца ,база данных MySQL?

Tags: c#, mysql, wpf

Делаю авторизацию в приложении Wpf ,используя БД MySQL.У меня есть админ и продавец. Суть простая при авторизации продавец вводит логин и пароль и открывается окно продавца. При этом надо запомнить или передать Seler_id(id продавца),чтобы при оплате товара ,вставлялся id продавца в ProductSales(Таблица продаж)
Не знаю как передать seller_id на главное окно и запомнить его.
Кто знает как правильно это реализовать ,помогите пожалуйста это сделать,пробавал по разному не получается
Приложу код авторизации

```
 private void Add_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

            string Connect = "Server=server232;port=3306;database=pos_product;UserId=serv232;password=123456; charset = utf8;";
            string CommandText = "SELECT Count(*) FROM  admin WHERE login = '" + login.Text + "' AND password = '" + password.Password + "' AND Status = '" + comboBox.Text + "' LIMIT 1 ";
            MySqlConnection myConnection = new MySqlConnection(Connect);
            MySqlCommand myCommand = new MySqlCommand(CommandText, myConnection);
            myConnection.Open();
            myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
            MySqlDataAdapter dataAdapter = new MySqlDataAdapter(myCommand);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dataAdapter.Fill(dt);
            if (dt.Rows[0][0].ToString() == "1")
            {
                AutoVxod();

            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Пожалуйста, проверьте правильность введенных данных!");
            }
        }
        public string[] SortList { get; set; } = {
                                        "Продавец",
                                        "Админ",
        };
        private void AutoVxod()
        {
            if (comboBox.Text == "Продавец")
            {

                this.Hide();
           
                string name = login.Text;
                MainWindow f2 = new MainWindow(name);
                f2.Show();
            }

            if (comboBox.Text == "Админ")
            {
                this.Hide();
                Windows.AdminWindow f2 = new Windows.AdminWindow();
                f2.Show();
            }

        }
    }
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Зачем эта вся возня с окнами? ) Не модно же уже https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1266479/373567, оставьте всякие Hide и Show в Winforms ) А потм, когда вы закрываете основное окно, приложение остается висеть в памяти, потому что окно логина не закрыто, а просто спрятано, проверьте диспетчер задач.

Comment: Понял,но я вопрос задавал по поводу авторизации.hide ,show-это я с интернета взял ,как пример .У меня проблема в том как сделать ,чтобы продавец после авторидации запоминался или отбображался на окне ,чтоб можно было его id использовать при купле продаже

Comment: `myConnection.Close()` еще забыли. Я не спец по БД, но не вижу проблемы отображать где-то строчку. Сделайте в окне `this.Title += $" - {name}";` и будет видно в заголовке окна.

Comment: Бопгадарю за ответ!

Comment: у вас продавец покупает товар или вам надо отображать купленные товары у определенного продавца?

Comment: Здравствуйте! Второе