# Как сделать, чтобы кнопка выделялась после нажатия? WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

попал в такую ситуацию. У меня есть форма в WPF, она выглядит вот так
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но у меня есть проблема. Мне нужно чтобы при выборе слева кнопки она как была выбрана, то есть при ее нажатие она выделялась как активная. Может кто подсказать как сделать. Я смог сделать, чтобы она просто при выделение выделялась
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
 <Style x:Key="menuButton" TargetType="Button">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#d0c0ff"/>
        <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{x:Null}"/>
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="35"/>
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="15 3"/>
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="13"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                    <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" CornerRadius="7">
                        <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>

        

        <Style.Triggers>
           <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="#7b5cd6"/>
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#ffffff"/>
            </Trigger>

        </Style.Triggers>
```

Я пробовал IsPressed, но они не выделялись тоже. Может кто подсказать как это сделать?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.primitives.togglebutton или если это меню, то почему не просто `ListBox`? https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1266479/373567

Comment: @aepot а вы не знаете насчет стиля? Может есть способ спомощью тригера это сделать?