# Как выйти со страницы на главный экран WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, button, окно

Возникла проблема с выходом на главный экран со страницы. При нажатии на кнопку на главном экране, меня перекидывает на страницу. Но вот обратно...На странице кнопка выхода совершенно другая.
Пример реализации выхода со страницы, но что-то не получилось.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: `MainWindow` - это окно, которое вы видите при запуске, основное, главное. В этом окне вы размещаете что либо из контента, в вашем случае наверно `Frame` (что зря), которому вы задаете разные странички. Вопрос теперь - почему вы хотите задать фрейму не страницу, а главное окно, которое у вас и так должно быть открыто? Так еще и новое главное окно, а не то, которое уже открыто...

Comment: @EvgeniyZ То, что `Frame` у меня находиться не в главном окне - это да. Просто, в таком случае мне придётся переделать программу. А как тогда можно вернуться на главный экран?

Comment: О каком главном экране идет речь? Почему `Frame у меня находиться не в главном окне`? О чем вы? Можете по-человечески объяснить, что там у вас происходит, дать нам код, самодостаточный пример, который можно запустить? А то смотрите, с таким объяснением могу тогда дать ответ такой: Вы не можете `Window` объект засунуть в контент фрейму. Все, вот ваша основная проблема. А как дальше поступать, зависит от того, что там и как. Скажу сразу, Frame для страниц не использую вообще.

Comment: Зачем вся это возня с фреймами. Они сделаны в WPF через зад. Начните с изучения привязок данных и MVVM. Это будет время, не потраченное зря. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1266479/373567. А кода освоите MVVM, придет время следующего этапа - IoC, и уже примерно в этот момент текущие проблемы вам покажутся детскими шалостями, потому что уровень уже будет другой совершенно. И до этого другого уровня нужно всего-лишь желание учиться и пара недель возни. И XAML будет как дом родной, потому что в нем интерфейс лепить проще, чем в C# в разы.

Comment: На текущий вопрос кроме того что "окно не может и никогда не могло быть контентом" больше нечего ответить. Так нельзя, и это не лечится. Если уж начали с фреймами, то в главном окне кроме фрейма ничего не должно быть, всё остальное - страницы. Тогда проблема решится сама собой.