# при нажатии на кнопку открывается нужная вкладка wpf

Tags: c#, wpf

Всем привет, у меня такой вопрос: как сделать так что при нажатии на кнопку открывается нужная вкладка в wpf и что бы открытая раннее вкладка скрывалась либо visible = hidden

```
<Window x:Class="kursach_kostenko_22.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:Icon="http://metro.mahapps.com/winfx/xaml/iconpacks"
        Height="720" Width="1080" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen" WindowStyle="None"
        AllowsTransparency="true" Background="Transparent">

    <Window.Resources>
        <BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BoolToVis"/>
    </Window.Resources>
    
    <Border Background="#eff2f7" CornerRadius="25" MouseDown="Border_MouseDown" MouseLeftButtonDown="Border_MouseLeftButtonDown">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="200"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            
                <!--Left menu-->
            <Grid>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            

            <!--Menu Icon-->
                <Button Margin="20,28,0,35" Style="{StaticResource topButton}">
                    <Icon:PackIconMaterial   Kind="Menu" Width="15" Height="15"/>
                </Button>

                <Border Grid.Row="1" Background="#623ed0" CornerRadius="0 50 0 25">
                    <DockPanel>
                        <!--Meno Logo-->
                        <Border Width="80" Height="80" Padding="3" Background="White" CornerRadius="100"
                                DockPanel.Dock="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="20 -30 0 0">
                            <Ellipse>
                                <Ellipse.Fill>
                                    <ImageBrush ImageSource="/images/p1.jpg"/>
                                </Ellipse.Fill>
                            </Ellipse>

                        </Border>
                        <!--Menu Titles-->
                        <TextBlock Text="Silver Club" Foreground="White" FontSize="22" FontWeight="SemiBold"
                                   DockPanel.Dock="Top" TextAlignment="Center" Margin="5 25 0 10"/>
                        <TextBlock Text="Member, France" Foreground="#d0bfff" FontSize="14" FontWeight="SemiBold"
                                   DockPanel.Dock="Top" TextAlignment="Center"/>

                        <!--Menu Separator-->
                        <Separator Margin="25" DockPanel.Dock="Top" Height="0.8" Background="#7e5fdc"/>

                        <!--Menu Buttons-->
                        <StackPanel DockPanel.Dock="Top">
                            <Button Style="{StaticResource menuButton}" Click="Button_Click_1">
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                    <Icon:PackIconMaterial Kind="HomeVariant" Style="{StaticResource menuButtonIcon}"/>
                                    <TextBlock Text="Dashboard"/>
                                </StackPanel>
                            </Button>

                            <Button Style="{StaticResource menuButton}">
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                    <Icon:PackIconMaterial Kind="CalendarClock" Style="{StaticResource menuButtonIcon}"/>
                                    <TextBlock Text="Events"/>
                                </StackPanel>
                            </Button>

                            <Button Style="{StaticResource menuButton}" Background="#7b5cd6" Foreground="White">
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                    <Icon:PackIconMaterial Kind="AccountMultipleOutline" Style="{StaticResource menuButtonIcon}"/>
                                    <TextBlock Text="Members"/>
                                </StackPanel>
                            </Button>

                            <Button Style="{StaticResource menuButton}" Click="Button_Click">
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                    <Icon:PackIconMaterial Kind="CashMultiple" Style="{StaticResource menuButtonIcon}"/>
                                    <TextBlock Text="Wallet"/>
                                </StackPanel>
                            </Button>

                            <Button Style="{StaticResource menuButton}">
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                    <Icon:PackIconMaterial Kind="ForumOutline" Style="{StaticResource menuButtonIcon}"/>
                                    <TextBlock Text="Messages"/>
                                </StackPanel>
                            </Button>

                            <Button Style="{StaticResource menuButton}" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" Margin="15 0 15 20">
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                    <Icon:PackIconMaterial Kind="Logout" Style="{StaticResource menuButtonIcon}"/>
                                    <TextBlock Text="Logout"/>
                                </StackPanel>
                            </Button>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DockPanel>
                </Border>
            </Grid>

                <!--Main Section-->
            <Grid x:Name="MainGrid" Grid.Column="1" Margin="30 20 20 20"  >
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>


                <!--Search Textbox-->
                <Grid Width="300" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                    <TextBlock Margin="20 0" VerticalAlignment="Center" Foreground="#b0b9c6" IsHitTestVisible="False"
                               Panel.ZIndex="1" Text="Search here ..."
                               Visibility="{Binding ElementName=txtSearch, Path=Text.IsEmpty,Converter={StaticResource BoolToVis}}"/>

                    <TextBox x:Name="txtSearch" Style="{StaticResource textboxSearch}" Height="35"/>

                    <Icon:PackIconMaterial Kind="Magnify" Width="15" Height="15" VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                           Margin="0 0 15 0" Foreground="#b0b9c6" HorizontalAlignment="Right"/>
                </Grid>

                <!--Top Buttons-->
                <Button Style="{StaticResource topButton}" Margin="0 0 20 0" Background="#dcdcdc" HorizontalAlignment="Right">
                    <Icon:PackIconMaterial Kind="Cog"/>
                </Button>

                <Button Style="{StaticResource topButton}" Margin="0 0 55 0" HorizontalAlignment="Right">
                    <Icon:PackIconMaterial Kind="Bell"/>
                </Button>
                
                <!--Page members-->
                <TextBlock Text="Members" Grid.Row="1" FontSize="32" FontWeight="SemiBold" Margin="0 20 0 0" 
                           HorizontalAlignment="Left" Foreground="#121518"/>

                <!--Add button-->
                <Button Style="{StaticResource addButton}">
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <Icon:PackIconMaterial Kind="Plus" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="11" Height="11" Margin="0 1 8 0"/>
                        <TextBlock Text="Add New Member"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </Button>
                
                <!--Separator-->
                <Separator Height="1" Grid.Row="3" Background="#dae2ea" Margin="0 -1 0 10"/>
                
                <!--Tab buttons-->
                <StackPanel Grid.Row="2" Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0 10 0 0">
                    <Button Content="Club Staff" Style="{StaticResource tabButton}" BorderBrush="#784ff2"/>
                    <Button Content="Players" Style="{StaticResource tabButton}"/>
                    <Button Content="Archived" Style="{StaticResource tabButton}"/>
                </StackPanel>


            </Grid>
        </Grid>
    </Border>
</Window>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1266044/373567

Comment: Главная ошибка новичков-разработчиков в том что сначала пилят рюшечки со стразиками красивыми, а потом начинают функции приложения делать, а должно быть равно наоборот.

Comment: Если речь о вкладках, то может быть `TabControl` - простое решение?

Comment: спасибо за ответ, пойду разбираться