# Как реализовать окно, содержащее большое количество других View? (MVVM C# WPF)

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, шаблоны-проектирования

Требуется реализовать отображение имеющихся продуктов в родительском окне категории. Окно категории - это UserControl, который должен содержать до 40 продуктов (UserControl`ов). Плохо знаком с MVVM и абсолютно не имею представления, как это можно реализовать.

Comment: Ну для начала, наверное, сделайте хоть как-нибудь. Потом посмотрите, оцените что не нравится и почему. В такой постановке проблемы как бы и нет.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1266479/373567