# WPF, MVVM, Переключение Content у ContentControl

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, usercontrol

Есть окно, в котором есть шапка с кнопками для переключения различных вкладок. Этими вкладками являются несколько UserControl. Окно имеет ContentControl после шапки, в котором я хочу располагать свои UserControl. Предполагается, что при нажатии определённой кнопки должен применяться соответствующий UserContent. Пожалуйста, подскажите, как я могу это реализовать?

Кнопка:

```
 <Button Width="200px" Command="{Binding AccomplishedPurchasesButton}">
                <Button.Background>
                    <SolidColorBrush Opacity="1"/>
                </Button.Background>
                <Label>
                    <TextBlock Text="Совершённые покупки"
                               TextWrapping="Wrap"
                               FontSize="28"
                               TextAlignment="Center"
                               LineStackingStrategy="BlockLineHeight"
                               LineHeight="30"
                    />
                </Label>
            </Button>
```

ContentControl:

```
<ContentControl x:Name="contentControl" Grid.Row="3" Content="{Binding CurrentVM}"/>
```

RelayCommand для кнопки:

```
private RelayCommand accomplishedPurchasesButton;
    public RelayCommand AccomplishedPurchasesButton
    {
        get
        {
            return accomplishedPurchasesButton ??
              (accomplishedPurchasesButton = new RelayCommand(obj =>
              {
                  CurrentVM = new PurchasePlan_UC_VM();
              }));
        }
    }
```

Я пытался применить разные способы, которые я смог найти, но так ничего и не смог, так как мне не хватает понимания и опыта работы с WPF и MVVM. Буду очень благодарен, если бы вы могли объяснить, что к чему. Скажите, если нужна дополнительная информация.

Реализация свойства CurrentVM

```
Base_VM currentVM;

    public Base_VM CurrentVM
    {
        get { return currentVM; }
        set
        {
            currentVM = value; 
            OnPropertyChanged("CurrentVM");
        }
    }
```

Comment: В таких случаю используют DataTemplate для ContentControl.ContentTemplate и DataTemplateSelector для выбора нужного DataTemplate.

Comment: Реализацию свойства `CurrentVM` покажите. Где INPC? https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1266479/373567

Comment: @aepot, Добавил

Comment: Выглядит нормально.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема решается с помощью использования DataTemplate.

В `Window.Resources` я разместил необходимые мне `DataTemplates`:

```xml
<Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type VM:AccomplishedPurchases_UC_VM}">
        <V:AccomplishedPurchases_UC/>
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type VM:PurchasePlan_UC_VM}">
        <V:PurchasePlan_UC/>
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>
```

Обе мои кнопки выглядят так:

```xml
<Button Width="150px" Command="{Binding PurchasePlanButton}" >
    <Button.Background>
        <SolidColorBrush Opacity="1"/>
    </Button.Background>
    <Label>
        <TextBlock Text="Purchase Plan"
                TextWrapping="Wrap"
                FontSize="28"
                TextAlignment="Center"
                LineStackingStrategy="BlockLineHeight"
                LineHeight="30"
        />
    </Label>
</Button>
```

И `ContentControl` имеет следующую привязку контента:

```xml
<ContentControl x:Name="contentControl" Grid.Row="3" Content="{Binding CurrentVM}"/>
```

`MainWindow ViewModel`:

```cs
Base_VM currentVM;

public Base_VM CurrentVM
{
    get { return currentVM; }
    set
    {
        currentVM = value; 
        OnPropertyChanged("CurrentVM");
    }
}

private RelayCommand accomplishedPurchasesButton;
public RelayCommand AccomplishedPurchasesButton
{
    get
    {
        return accomplishedPurchasesButton ??
          (accomplishedPurchasesButton = new RelayCommand(obj =>
          {
              CurrentVM = new AccomplishedPurchases_UC_VM();
          }));
    }
}

private RelayCommand purchasePlanButton;
public RelayCommand PurchasePlanButton
{
    get
    {
        return purchasePlanButton ??
          (purchasePlanButton = new RelayCommand(obj =>
          {
              CurrentVM = new PurchasePlan_UC_VM();
          }));
    }
}
```

`Base_VM` реализует `INotifyPropertyChanged`.