# WPF C# Pages навигация без MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, frame

Имеется приложение WPF. Есть Frame, с помощью которого при запуске приложения мне нужно отобразить одну из двух страниц. Пускай это будет Page1.xaml

Как реализовать эту идею без MVVM? Очень срочно нужно, я новичок, в этой модели разобраться за 3 дня не смогу. Буду очень благодарен!

Comment: MVVM очень прост, максимально, зря вы его боитесь. Это ведь не какой либо инструмент, или еще что, нет, это просто набор правил, которым надо следовать. Сами правила основаны на базовых механизмах WPF, а именно привязки (Binding) и XAML, все. А вот если вы не знаете базовые механизмы, тот тут уже да, проблема. Что касается вашего вопроса - не пойму в чем трудности? Берете и вызываете метод `Navigate()`, которому передаете экземпляр нужной страницы, готово.

Comment: Без MVVM сам по себе WPF - это набор костылей. MVVM и привязки данных используют для того, чтобы писать приложение было проще, а не потому что это модно или красиво. Примеров того что вы спрашиваете куча https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1266479/373567