# Как организовать навигацию между страницами с помощью MVVM Toolkit?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, page

Продолжаю свое изучение MVVM с MVVM Toolkit. Вопрос таков - как правильнее и красивее всего сделать навигацию между страницами в WPF?

Comment: Что именно не получается? Правильнее и красивее чем что? На чистом WPF можно вот так https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1266479/373567

Comment: MVVM Toolkit - это просто генератор кода за вас, который базовые механизмы MVVM меняет на простые атрибуты. Сам подход к созданию проекта всегда +- один. Советую вам отказаться от MVVM Toolkit и изучить сначала основы, как это все делается на чистом C#, а уж потом облегчайте жизнь библиотеками.

Comment: Присоединяюсь к комментарию @EvgeniyZ, потом дойдете до библиотек, для страниц и IoC отлично подходит Prism.WPF