# Как правильно менять целевой ContentControl?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, usercontrol, navigation

Дано следующее: есть форма MainWindow, внутри неё есть ContentControl, в который подгружается нужный UserControl. UserControl несколько штук. Соблюдаем MVVM, все дела. Делается это посредством некоего Navigator класса:

```
InvokeInMainThread(() =>
        {
            Type view = GetView(target);
            Type viewModel = ViewModelPairs[view];
            var data = viewModel.GetConstructor(BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance, null, new Type[1] { GetType() }, null).Invoke(args);
            var content = (FrameworkElement)Activator.CreateInstance(view);
            content.DataContext = data;
            _frameControl.Content = content;
        });
```

примерно по такой логике: в каждую ViewModel передаётся этот Navigator, нажатие кнопки запускает описанный выше метод, где target - строка, имя UserControl, который нужно показать (пишется, кстати, в коде руками, это правильно с точки зрения паттерна?), ViewModel берётся из заранее синициализированного Dictionary. Вопрос заключается в следующем: внутри нескольких UserControl есть свои ContentControl, а _frameControl у Navigator присваивается с началом запуска приложения. Как и откуда будет правильно брать ContentControl, в который необходимо грузить UserControl?

Мои предположения следующие:

1. В каждый UserControl добавить ссылку на родительский ContentControl, но передавать ссылки между UserControl во-первых неверно архитектурно, а во-вторых без понятия как сделать.
2. С каждой кнопкой передавать ссылку на ContentControl, что архитектурно тоже ошибочно.

Проше не предлагать другие реализации навигации, интересует именно эта реализация.

Если вдруг проблема не ясна приведу простой пример: есть Window, внутри которой есть ContentControl1, в который Navigator по запросу VM поместит UserControl1, в котором есть свой ContentControl2 и кнопка в UserControl1 должна попросить Navigator поместить туда содержимое UserControl2. У Navigator есть _frameControl (целевой ContentControl). Как правильно с точки зрения MVVM получить _frameControl?

Comment: Если компоненту нужна зависииость, передайте ее в этот компонент при его создании. А вообще здесь IoC напрашивается. По поводу свича вьюх я бы лучше использовал DataTemplate https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1266479/373567, не пришлось бы лепить костыли а рефлексии. Здесь надо понять, велосипед изобретаете по незнанию или добровольно?

Comment: А еще лучше Prism :)