# Почему не работает переключение состояний?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, вкладки

**Ситуация:** я создаю меню в котором есть действия, одно из действий должно переключить `frame` на следующий кадр/состояние.

**Проблема**: Оно не работает, хотя `DataContext` подключён и нету ошибок привязки.

**Минимальный воспроизводимый пример**: В `App.xaml` удаляем `StartupUri`( вроде так...), затем в `App.xaml.cs` пишем код:

```cs
public partial class App : Application
{
    private static Page one = new Page1();
    private static Page two = new Page2();

    Tabs tabs = new Tabs() { One = one, Two = two, Current = one};

    protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs args)
    {
        base.OnStartup(args);

        one.DataContext = tabs;
        two.DataContext = tabs;

        new MainWindow() { DataContext = tabs}.Show();
    }
}
```

Создать `Tab.cs` и прописать вот это:

*Минутка пояснения: этот код содержит страницы и команду открытия. Кнопка или что-то другое, вызывает команду с параметром страницы. Здесь `RelayCommand` для работы)*

```
public class RelayCommand : ICommand
{
    private Action<object> execute;
    private Func<object, bool> canExecute;

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
    {
        add { CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value; }
        remove { CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value; }
    }

    public RelayCommand(Action<object> execute, Func<object, bool> canExecute = null)
    {
        this.execute = execute;
        this.canExecute = canExecute;
    }

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return this.canExecute == null || this.canExecute(parameter);
    }

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        this.execute(parameter);
    }
}

public class Tabs : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private Page _One;
    private Page _Two;
         
    public Page One
    {
        get => _One;
        set
        {
            _One = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("selected");
        }
     }
     public Page Two
     {
         get => _Two;
         set
         {
            _Two = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("selected");
         }
     }

     private Page _Current;

     public Page Current
     {
        get => _Current;
        set
        {
            _Current = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("selected");
        }
    }

    public ICommand Open => new RelayCommand(obj => Current = (Page)obj);

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string prop = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(prop));
    }
}
```

Создаём страницы `Page1` и `Page2`, в первой создаём кнопку:

```
<Button Content="1" Margin="10" FontSize="50" Command="{Binding Open}" CommandParameter="{Binding Two}"/>
```

Во второй:

```
<Button Content="2" Margin="10" FontSize="50" Command="{Binding Open}" CommandParameter="{Binding One}"/>
```

При запуске ничего не происходит.

Может я что-то опускаю?

Comment: `OnPropertyChanged("selected");` везде замените на `OnPropertyChanged();` параметром должно передаваться название свойства, но за вас это подцепит `[CallerMemberName]`

Comment: Ссылка в тему https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1266479/373567

Comment: У меня было подобное, но другой подход. Можете посмотреть мой ответ в теме, решение которое помогло мне.
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1504892/c-listbox-wpf-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%b2%d1%8f%d0%b7%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%86%d1%8b-entinty-framework

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Благодаря @aepot я смог решить проблему - убрав аргумент `selected`.

> `OnPropertyChanged("selected");` везде замените на `OnPropertyChanged();` параметром должно передаваться название свойства, но за вас это подцепит `[CallerMemberName]`

**Спасибо тем кто участвовал в решение проблемы**