# C# Listbox WPF привязка таблицы entinty framework

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, listbox

У меня есть `Listbox`, который при запуске я заполняю из базы данных `ef`, но при изменении коллекции у меня не обновляются данные в форме

Код `DataContext`:

```
  public class DataContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<ChatDb> ChatDb { get; set; } = null!;
        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            string path = "Data Base";
            if (!Directory.Exists(path))
                Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
            optionsBuilder.UseSqlite(@$"Data Source={path}\\Data Base.db");
        }
    }
```

Код класса `ChatDb`:

```
 public class ChatDb
    {
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
        [Key]
        public string ID { get; set; } = null!;
        public string Name { get; set; } = null!;
    }
```

Так заполняю коллекцию

```
 using (DataContext db = new DataContext())
            {
                db.Database.EnsureCreated();
                ChatDb chatDb = new ChatDb() { Name = "ddd", ID = "ssss" };
                db.ChatDb.Add(chatDb);
                lock (this)
                    db.SaveChanges();
                ListBoxChats.ItemsSource = db.ChatDb.ToList();
            }
        }
```

Код `ListBox`:

```
<ListBox Style="{DynamicResource ListBoxStyleRound}" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" x:Name="ListBoxChats" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="3" Grid.RowSpan="7" MaxHeight="198" Background="#FFFFFF" BorderBrush="#A8A8A8" Margin="5,0,51,0" SelectionChanged="ListBoxChats_SelectionChanged" >
                <ListBox.DataContext>
                    <Model:ChatDb ID="ID" Name="Name"/>
                </ListBox.DataContext>

                <ListBox.ItemTemplate >
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Grid Grid.Column="0">
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
                                <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
                                <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <TextBlock x:Name="Tbs" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" FontSize="14" Margin="3,0,0,0" Text="{Binding Name, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
                            <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" Text="{Binding ID, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Margin="3,0,0,5" />
                            <Rectangle Stroke="#EBEBEB" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" RadiusX="2" RadiusY="2" />
                            <Button x:Name="DeleteChat" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="2" Padding="3" FontSize="15" BorderBrush="Transparent" Background="Transparent" Foreground="Red" Click="DeleteChat_Click" Content="X"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            </ListBox>
```

Я могу заполнять через `ObservableCollection`, реализую интерфейс `INotifyPropertyChanged` и все данные редактируются и т.п. А со связкой базы данных `ef` не получается, и не понял для класса `ChatDb` реализовать интерфейс `INotifyPropertyChanged`.

Comment: В нормальном WPF проекте принято разделять все на мало связанные друг с другом слои, зовется этот подход MVVM. В таком подходе, все ваши данные (база и получение всего) - это Model слой. Ваш XAML (UI со всеми стилями, кнопками, и прочим) - это View слой. Ну и связующий слой, который попросит данные из М слоя, создаст свойства для привязок V слоя, обработает от V все команды - это ViewModel. Другими словами, логика такая: Класс Model, в нем методы работы с базой, класс  ViewModel, в нем свойства для привязки и методы, которые дергают модель. XAML просто привязывается к свойствам.

Comment: Обновление же базы - отлавливаете изменение данных в коллекции (у `ObservableCollection` есть нужное событие), и по вызову этого события смотрите какой именно объект был удален/изменен/добавлен, эти изменения и отсылаете в базу.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ то есть мне все же нужно привязывать listbox к ObservableCollection в любом случае? То есть у меня коллекция ObservableCollection  и при ее изменение я отслеживаю изменения и изменяю базу данных ef? Напрямую базу данных не выйдет привязать? Я wpf недавно начал изучать, только разобрался со основной, так что не судите строго)

Comment: Привязать напрямую вроде можно, но это дает ряд проблем. Одной из таких проблем является постоянное дергание базы по малейшему чиху, что приведет к ее сильной нагрузке. Тут лучше собрать все изменения и разом их отправить. Еще проблема в том, что будет постоянно висеть `DbContext`, что тоже может привести к своим проблемам. Это я еще молчу про то, что прямое соединение M и V слоев - это нарушение MVVM (если на нем будете писать), ибо по правилам MVVM UI не должен знать ничего про другие слои, включая Model. Так что да, яб на вашем месте сделал коллекцию и по ее событие обновлял базу.

Comment: При каждом создании контекста проверка существования каталога... EnsureCreated()... lock(this)... / ChatGPT, родненький, развивайся скорее, заменишь этих...

Comment: `ListBoxChats.ItemsSource = null; ListBoxChats.ItemsSource = db.ChatDb.ToList();`

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov не при каждом написано в событии load один раз, далее закомментировано. Вопрос в теме не про это)

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Мне было бы удобнее если привязано напрямую было бы, так как делать коллекцию и базу данных для одного элемента и по всем событиям дважды писать код, не очень классно

Comment: Я всё таки привязал таблицу базы данных к listbox, данные грузятся и редактируются. Проверю немного ещё и выложу решение здесь.

Answer (score 0):

Решение которое работает у меня
Класс DataContext

```
  public class DataContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<ChatDb> ChatDb { get; set; } = null!;
        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            string path = "Data Base";
            if (!Directory.Exists(path))
                Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
            optionsBuilder.UseSqlite(@$"Data Source={path}\\Data Base.db");
        }
    }
```

Таблица с данными

```
public class ChatDb
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string ChatId { get; set; } = null!;
        public string Name { get; set; } = null!;
    }
```

Listbox

```
    <ListBox Style="{DynamicResource ListBoxStyleRound}" ItemsSource="{Binding ChatDb}"  HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" x:Name="ListBoxChats" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="3" Grid.RowSpan="7" MaxHeight="198" Background="#FFFFFF" BorderBrush="#A8A8A8" Margin="5,0,51,0" SelectionChanged="ListBoxChats_SelectionChanged" >
           <ListBox.ItemTemplate >
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid Grid.Column="0">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <TextBlock x:Name="Tbs" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" FontSize="14" Margin="3,0,0,0" Text="{Binding Name, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" Text="{Binding ChatId, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Margin="3,0,0,5" />
                    <Rectangle Stroke="#EBEBEB" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" RadiusX="2" RadiusY="2" />
                    <Button x:Name="DeleteChat" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="2" Padding="3" FontSize="15" BorderBrush="Transparent" Background="Transparent" Foreground="Red" Click="DeleteChat_Click" Content="X"/>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
```

MainWindow

```
using Casis.Model;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using System;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Media;

namespace Casis
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {

        DataContext db = new DataContext();
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Loaded += Window_Loaded;
            GridSms.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
            GridComands.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
            GridPosting.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
            GridGlavnaya.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        }
        private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            db.Database.EnsureCreated();
            // загружаем данные из БД
            db.ChatDb.Load();
            // и устанавливаем данные в качестве контекста
            ListBoxChats.ItemsSource = db.ChatDb.Local.ToObservableCollection();
        }
        //Добавление
     private void BtnAddChat_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
                var chatModel = new ChatDb() { Name = TbChatName.Text, ChatId = TbChat.Text };
                db.ChatDb.Add(chatModel);
                db.SaveChanges();
                ListBoxChats.Items.Refresh();
        }
        //Редактирование
        private void TbName_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            BtnAddChatBackground();
            var chatName = ListBoxChats.SelectedItem as ChatDb;
            if (chatName == null)
                return;
            var res = db.ChatDb.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == chatName.Name);
            if (res != null)
            {
                res.Name = TbChatName.Text;
                db.SaveChanges();
                ListBoxChats.Items.Refresh();
            }
        }
 
        //Удаление
        private void DeleteChat_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (ListBoxChats.SelectedItems != null)
            {
                var SelectedItem = ((ListBoxItem)ListBoxChats.ContainerFromElement((Button)sender)).Content;
                if (SelectedItem == null)
                    return;
                if (SelectedItem is ChatDb chatModel)
                {
                    db.ChatDb.Remove(chatModel);
                    db.SaveChanges();
                    ListBoxChats.Items.Refresh();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ну, вы сделали то, что я вам и говорил) Сделали коллекцию, в которую грузите данные из базы, а затем при помощи событий (правда не самой коллекции) сами, вручную меняете значения в базе)

Comment: db.ChatDb.Load();
            // и устанавливаем данные в качестве контекста
            ListBoxChats.ItemsSource = db.ChatDb.Local.ToObservableCollection();
        } за счет этого данные которые связаны обновляются, подход удобен сам по себе, и не обязательно чтобы контекст висел все время, можно через using очищать контекст сразу.