# Взаимосвязь между несколькими ViewModel (C#)

Tags: c#, wpf

Нужно реализовать грамотную связь между множеством `ViewModel`, какие есть наилучшие варианты реализации?

Существует 2 основные `ViewModel`:

Одна `ViewModel` осуществляет поиск по базе данных и отображение данных в `ListBox`.

Вторая `ViewModel` - это `TabItem`.

Связь между ними простая: при нажатии на элемент `ListBox` необходимо передать `id` элемента (каждый элемент - клиент, у которого есть `id` и другие данные) или передать элемент целиком, пока ещё не определился.

Вторая `ViewModel` принимает данный `id` или класс и добавляет его в коллекцию. Каждый элемент этой коллекции - отдельный `TabItem`.

Далее, внутри каждого `TabItem` есть основная `ViewModel`, которая будет показывать содержимое `TabItem` по некоторому условию. У каждого содержимого есть своя `ViewModel`.

Далее каждый уровень - это отдельная `ViewModel`.

---

**1 уровень:**

`ViewModel` для окна с просмотром некоторой информации по базе данных в целом (Отчет за период). Внутри больше нет моделей.

`ViewModel` добавления/редактирования информации о клиенте. Имя, Фамилия, номер телефона и список его автомобилей.

---

**2 уровень:**

`ViewModel` добавления/редактирования информации о выбранном автомобиле из списка автомобилей клиента уровнем выше. Марка, производитель, номер авто, список визитов данного автомобиля в сервис и т.д.

---

**3 уровень:**

`ViewModel` добавление/редактирования информации о выбранном визите из списка визитов автомобиля клиента уровнем выше.

---

Больше уровней нет.

Необходимо грамотно продумать связь между `ViewModel`. Какие есть лучшие варианты? Можете показать подобные примеры или скинуть ссылку на примеры реализации?

Буду благодарен, спасибо!

Comment: Путаница. `ListBox` или `TabItem` не могут иметь отношение к View Model, так как это View слой. Вопрос в целом на воображение, я с ходу не могу понять, что у вас там происходит. Быть может стоит написать [воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? Что такое "связь" в вашем понимании? Зачем она?

Comment: Передавать информацию между моделями, чтобы изменять те или другие свойства

Comment: Например - нажали на ListItem - открылся TabItem с информацией. При этом, ListBox находится в SearchPageViewModel, а TabItem находится в другой модели (не помню уже название)

Comment: Разные потребности решаются по-разному. Но в целом решение - ссылка на экземпляр нужной вьюмодели. Меню что-ли у вас там?

Comment: Singleton не лучший вариант. Думаю использовать Service, а другие модели будут подписаны на него, но не знаю как правильно реализовать

Comment: [Оно?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1266479/373567) Ну или почитайте про шаблон проектирования IoC (инверсия управления).

Comment: Лучший вариант - использование Prism и его регионов. При клике по списку вы будете делать навигацию во втором регионе(там ваши более подробные данные) и перед этим передавать во ViewModel ваш id или другие данные. Не нравится Prism - сделайте Service, в котором будете хранить выделенный элемент. Зарегистрируйте его в контейнере как Singleton и используйте в каждой VM.

Comment: Здесь можно посмотреть примеры. https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism-Samples-Wpf

Comment: @Lapish Prism для больших проектов

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/live/AkJ52O3cgi0?si=Bd7m_yvcGAiuVz7K

Нашел такое видео, попробую посмотреть.

Comment: @aepot а что мешает его использовать для небольших проектов? В нем уже есть 2 DI-контейнера(что нужно автору), а сконфигурировать его для своих задач - дело пары минут.

Comment: @Lapish ничего не мешает. Я за то чтобы учиться руками пилить код, а уже потом переходить на библиотеки размером с 3 проекта. Автор не знает, что такое DI.

Comment: @Lapish, как правильно реализовать через Service, можете написать простой пример ?

Comment: @АндрейШутов да, сейчас подготовлю.

Comment: @Lapish, спасибо Вам большое!!!

Comment: @АндрейШутов https://github.com/Lapish/ExampleVMCommunication Базовый способ, но для понимания думаю пойдет.

Comment: @Lapish, у меня используется в app  Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection и Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting. Они вместе могут взаимодействовать?

Comment: @АндрейШутов Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting вам явно не нужно. Вы можете подключить любой DI-контейнер. Я использовал DryIoc, но их очень много. Раньше(не знаю как сейчас) очень популярным был Unity. Если не хотите подключать DI или пока не получается, то просто сделайте ваш класс singleton'ом через паттерн https://metanit.com/sharp/patterns/2.3.php

Comment: @АндрейШутов если не используете, то советую MaterialDesignXAML библиотеку. Это material-стиль для wpf приложения. Но самое главное - возможность легкого создания одностраничного приложения с помощью DialogHost. Т.е, вы можете не создавать новое окно, а внутри вашего единственного окна выводить что-то поверх. Можете скачать [DemoApp](https://github.com/MaterialDesignInXAML/MaterialDesignInXamlToolkit/releases/tag/v4.9.0) и во вкладке Dialogs посмотреть, что я имею ввиду.