# Как правильно структурировать приложение согласно паттерну MVVM? (Xamarin.forms)

Tags: c#, mvvm, xamarin

Я создаю приложение, которое должно общаться с микроконтроллером ESP32 по bluetooth low energy. Класс ble
должен отправлять данные на esp и получать их назад.   Внутри приложения должны быть классы режимов работы, выбираемые пользователем. Например: класс, запрашивающий данные о погоде по http запросу и отправляющий их на микроконтроллер и т.д. Также должен быть класс "распределитель", вызывающий эти режимы в зависимости от полученных от микроконтроллера данных.

**Как я вижу этот проект:**

Имеется класс-синглтон `BleController`, отвечающий за взаимодействие с esp. Он имеет событие, которое срабатывает при поступлении новых данных, и метод, отправляющий новые данные на esp.
Класс-распределитель (тоже синглтон) имеет у себя лист режимов, которые являются наследниками интерфейса. Он подписан на событие получения новых данных и вызывает нужный режим в зависимости от этих данных.

Также имеется примитивный графический интерфейс с кнопками "подключить", "отключить", списком доступных режимов и списком устроиств, доступных для подключения.

Вопросы:

- Является ли `BleController` сервисом и как его правильно создать?
- Прямое обращение к нему от режимов является нарушением mvvm?
- Чем должен быть класс-распределитель (сервис, модель, синглтон и т.д.)?
- Являются ли режимы моделями или чем-то другим?
- Правильно ли мое видение программы с точки зрения паттерна?

Comment: В вопросе не хватает вашей попытки это сделать. А как бы вы поступили в данной ситуации?

Comment: @aepot Я бы сделал класс-синглтон ble, который бы имел событие, срабатывающее при поступлении новых данных и обычный метод, отправляющий данные на esp. Класс-распределитель имел бы лист режимов-наследников одного интерфейса, которые бы вызывались при обработке входящих данных. В разных примерах я вижу папку "services", но не могу найти информацию о том, что в ней должно располагаться и как с этими сервисами работать. Я и хотел уточнить, является ли класс ble и распределитель сервисами, можно ли к ним напрямую обращаться и к чему относятся классы-режимы?

Comment: Допишите лучше эту информацию в сам вопрос.

Comment: @aepot добавил. Спасибо за подсказку

Comment: А почему синглтон? Неужели недостаточно, чтобы единственность объекта определялась бизнес-логикой?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

По сути вам уже дали ответ на ваши вопросы, я лишь этим ответом хочу показать то, как можно поступить, некий подход проектирования, который имеет мало связанные друг с другом объекты, использует сервисы и DI контейнер.

И так, MVVM, это когда все разделено на мало связанные друг с другом слои, где

- Model - это слой с вашими данными. Конкретно в вашем случае `BleController`, это Model.
- ViewModel - слой, который общается с Model и предоставляет для UI необходимые публичные свойства для привязки.
- View - слой с нашим UI, то есть вся XAML разметка и все то, что видит пользователь.

То есть, все наше приложение становится максимально удобно для внедрения чего-либо нового или изменения старого, а если все это еще и завязывать на абстракции, то мы вовсе можем сделать проект, который состоит из кучи маленьких.

Что такое **сервис**: Создавать объекты самостоятельно, это порой муторно и зачастую портит ту самую "слабую связь" между объектами, ведь мы явно указываем `= new SomeClass();`. Небольшой пример:

```
ILogger 
{
   void Send(string msg);
}

class FileLogger : ILogger
{
    public void Send(string msg)
    {
        // Записываем в файл наш лог.
    }
}

class SomeClass
{
    ILogger logger = new FileLogger(); // new ServerLogger() // new ConsoleLogger() ...

    void Method() => logger.Send("Данные в лог");
}
```

Предположим, что `SomeClass`, это некий класс, который находится у нас в библиотеке, ну и тут сразу думаю становится очевидно то, что он имеет зависимость от класса `Logger` и от интерфейса `ILogger`, что не есть хорошо. Ок, перепишем его следующим образом:

```
class SomeClass
{
    ILogger logger;

    public SomeClass(ILogger logger)
        => this.logger = logger;

    public void Method() => logger.Send("Данные в лог");
}
```

Мы с вами сделали Dependency Injection (DI), то есть внедрили зависимость в наш класс за его пределами, что позволяет теперь ему существовать **только** ссылаясь на интерфейс.
Имея это, мы можем теперь полностью убрать из нашего проекта все `= new ... ();`, как? Да все просто, при помощи контейнеров.

Контейнер - это некая реализация, которая в себе хранит зарегистрированные типы и объекты и в случае необходимости, отдает их при помощи DI или прямого запроса. Если очень грубо объяснять, то контейнер, это словарь объектов/типов, который обычно только раз настраивается и больше про него не вспоминают. Давайте приведу простой псевдокод:

Предположим, что у нас есть те классы, что выше и есть контейнер, в который мы добавляем эти зависимости:

```
class Program
{
    ILogger logger;
    SomeClass someClass;

    public Program(ILogger logger, SomeClass someClass)
        => (this.logger, this.someClass) = (logger, someClass);

    public void SomeLogic()
    {
        var result = "Некие данные";
        someClass.Method();
        logger.Send(result); // логируем их.
    }
}

var container = new SomeContainer();
container.Register<SomeClass>();
container.Register<ILogger, Logger>();
container.Register<Program>();

var program = container.Resolve<Program>();
program.SomeLogic();
```

Здесь мы зарегистрировали нужные нам типы в контейнере и дальше попросили из него лишь один объект (`Program`), в который он сам внедрил все необходимые зависимости, нам не нужно хардкодить `= new Logger(); .. = new SomeClass(logger);`, нет, это все сделает за нас контейнер, добавляй только нужные типы, да и все.

Но ок, как это все связано с сервисами? Честно, могу ошибаться, но понятие "сервис" пошло от ASP.NET, где весь проект и строится на DI и контейнере, а все зависимости, которые регистрируются в контейнере и называются "сервис". То есть, сервис, это некий класс, который имеет нужную нам логику, допустим, работа с базой, ну и сам этот сервис лежит в контейнере.

**Ничего не понятно, можно пример?**

Знаете, в WPF и Xamarin проектах, всю эту схему очень классно раскрывает один весьма популярный пакет, зовется Prism. С вашего позволения, я сделаю WPF проект на его основе, а там вам не составит труда подставить свои компоненты и адаптировать все под Xamarin.

1. Создаем новый проект (у меня WPF).
2. Устанавливаем из NuGet один из DI контейнеров под Prism, я возьму `Prism.DryIoc`, он также подтянет `Prism.Wpf`, `DryIoc.dll` и ряд других зависимостей.
3. Создаем две папки `Views` и `ViewModels`.
4. Переносим `MainWindow` в `Views`, попутно поправляя в ней все `namespace`.
5. Переписываем стартовую точку проекта:

   - Открываем `App.xaml` и добавляем туда пространство имен `xmlns:prism="http://prismlibrary.com/"`
   - Удаляем `StartupUri`
   - Меняем `<Application` на `<prism:PrismApplication`
   - Открываем `App.xaml.cs` и убираем там наследование от `: Application`
   - Реализуем все необходимое, следуя подсказкам студии. У нас будет два переписанных метода:

     - `CreateShell()` - он отвечает за создание основного окна нашего проекта, некий аналог `StartupUri` из `App.xaml`, только окно берется из контейнера, со всеми зависимостями. Нам достаточно просто написать в нем `return Container.Resolve<MainWindow>();`
     - `RegisterTypes(IContainerRegistry containerRegistry)` - метод, в котором мы регистрируем все необходимые нам типы для контейнера.

       В итоге получим нечто такое:

       ```
         public partial class App
         {
             protected override Window CreateShell()
                 => Container.Resolve<MainWindow>();

             protected override void RegisterTypes(IContainerRegistry containerRegistry)
             {
                 // Регистрируем сервисы и другие типы.
             }
         }
       ```
6. В классе окна прописываем `xmlns:prism="http://prismlibrary.com/"` и `prism:ViewModelLocator.AutoWireViewModel="True"`. Эта позволит автоматически находить ViewModel для окна.
7. Сделаем вывод текста, простой `TextBlock` по центру окна и привязанный к свойству `Text`

   ```
   <TextBlock Text="{Binding Text}" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" FontSize="30"/>
   ```
8. В папке `ViewModels` сделаем класс `*ViewModel`, где `*` это название наше View. То есть делаем `MainWindowViewModel`. Если View зовется `SomeView`, то VM должна называться `SomeViewModel`, а не `SomeViewViewModel`!.
9. В созданном VM классе делаем то самое свойство, которое мы привязали:

   ```
   public string Text { get; set; } = "Привет мир!";
   ```

В итоге на данном этапе наш проект выглядит так:

[image: Project]

Можем уже запускать

[image: Project result]

Я думаю, вы уже заметили, что в архитектуре нашего проекта нету каких-либо `= new .. ()`, все мало связанно друг с другом и работа идет через контейнер зависимостей. Теперь давайте добавим еще больше магии...

1. Добавим в наше решение новый проект, библиотеку классов, назовем `[названиеПроекта].Services.Interfaces`, чтоб не запутаться и поместим его в директорию `Services`. Этот проект пусть отвечает только за интерфейсы.
2. Создадим в этом проекте интерфейс, не будем отходить от "традиций", пусть будет, как и ранее `ILogger`, некий интерфейс, который отвечает за логирование проекта.

   ```
    public interface ILogger
    {
        event Action<string> OnNewLog;
        void Send(string message);
    }
   ```
3. Для наглядности, сделаем еще один интерфейс, просто чтобы вы поняли суть, назовем его `ITime`, пусть отвечает за получение времени:

   ```
    public interface ITime
    {
        DateTime GetTime();
    }
   ```
4. Создадим еще один проект, также в директории `Service` и назовем его `LoggerService`, добавим ему в зависимости ранее созданный проект интерфейсов, а в нем класс, который будет реализовывать интерфейс `ILogger`, к примеру так:

   ```
    public class FileLoggerService : ILogger
    {
        public event Action<string> OnNewLog;
        public ITime time;

        public FileLoggerService(ITime time)
            => this.time = time;

        public void Send(string message)
        {
            // Делаем нечто с сообщением.
            OnNewLog?.Invoke($"[{time.GetTime().ToShortTimeString()}] {message}");
        }
    }
   ```

   Заметьте, мы не знаем чего-либо про реализацию `ITime`, мы даже не можем написать `time = new ...()`, ибо попросту нету этого класса, мы знаем только то, что есть некий интерфейс, не более. Это отлично показывает то, как слабо связаны друг с другом слои и проекты в целом, ведь реализация `ITime` может быть где угодно, хоть также, в отдельном проекте.
5. К основному проекту подключаем `SOProject.Services.Interfaces` и `SOProject.Services.LoggerService`.
6. Делаем реализацию `ITIme`:

   ```
    public class TimeNow : ITime
    {
        public DateTime GetTime()
            => DateTime.Now;
    }
   ```
7. Регистрируем в контейнер все типы:

   ```
    protected override void RegisterTypes(IContainerRegistry containerRegistry)
    {
        // Регистрируем сервисы и другие типы.
        containerRegistry.Register<ILogger, FileLoggerService>();
        containerRegistry.Register<ITime, TimeNow>();
    }
   ```
8. Переписываем `MainWindowViewModel`:

   ```
    public class MainWindowViewModel
    {
        private ILogger logger;
        public MainWindowViewModel(ILogger logger)
        {
            this.logger = logger;
            SendLogCommand = new DelegateCommand<string>(log => logger.Send(log));
            this.logger.OnNewLog += log => Logs.Add(log);
        }

        public ObservableCollection<string> Logs { get; } = new();
        public ICommand SendLogCommand { get; }        
    }
   ```

   Тут все просто, мы получаем логгер через DI, а также делаем коллекцию, куда будем писать сообщения и команду, которая будет отправлять в логгер сообщение, а также мы подписываемся на событие, которое добавит нам в коллекцию сообщение.
9. Осталось реализовать View:

   ```
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Logs}"/>
        <Grid Grid.Row="1">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition/>
                <ColumnDefinition/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <TextBox Grid.Column="0" x:Name="logText"/>
            <Button Grid.Column="1"
                    Command="{Binding SendLogCommand}"
                    CommandParameter="{Binding Text, ElementName=logText}"
                    Content="Отправить"/>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
   ```

Запускаем, смотрим

[image: Service Result]

Заметьте, это все идет через наш сервис, который мы получили через все тот же интерфейс. Сам проект в итоге выглядит так:

[image: Project]

Вот вам и реализация проекта по правилам MVVM, с DI контейнерами, ну и с сервисами, где все мало связано друг с другом, что дает максимальные возможности для тестирования и дальнейшего развития, ведь если нам нужна будет новая логика, мы ее можем сделать также в новой DLL, которую потом достаточно будет зарегистрировать в контейнере и использовать там, где нам надо.

Prism я тут взял как хорошего помощника, который позволяет очень многое, хоть делайте модули, которые будут автоматически подключаться в проект, находясь с ним в одной директории, хоть делите View на слои. Но тут должны сами понимать, все зависит от проекта и ваших желаний, вы можете вовсе все это делать в одном проекте и использовать чисто MVVM подход, вам не запрещают. Главное, поймите суть этого всего и знайте, что такая возможность существует.

Comment: Спасибо, очень хорошее объяснение.

Comment: @AndrewPstvt Главное, чтобы вы это поняли, а то мои старания были напрасны) Ну а так, да не за что, удачи в изучении, если что, спрашивайте.

Comment: Спасибо! Не напрасно) Узнал о DI, так ещё и по сервисам которые меня интересовали)

Comment: @EvgeniyZ как быть с View ? При внедрении зависимости во ViewModel - View ругается что нет открытого конструктора( А точнее BindingContext у View `<viewModels:NotesViewModel/>`

Comment: @Xzizz Это нарушение MVVM. Указав в XAML так `DataContext`, ваша View 1. Знает про ViewModel (когда не должна). 2. Отвечает за ViewModel (когда не должна). Об этом есть [хороший ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/562586/220553).

Comment: @EvgeniyZ мдеее... Это же прям из Learn.Microsoft по MVVM https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/maui/tutorials/notes-mvvm/?tutorial-step=6

Comment: @Xzizz Ну, MVVM это набор **рекомендаций**, которым каждый следует по своему. Кто-то мешает слои, кто-то нет; кто-то использует события по типу `Click`, а другие нет. Тут стоит смотреть на реалии конкретного проекта, как он изначально базируется, на чем, и так далее. В "чистом" MVVM, у вас должно быть все разделено на мало связанные друг с другом слои, где View не знает про VM и M,  ViewModel не знает про View, а Model как и View не знает ничего про VM и V, ну а установка VM в V слое сами понимаете, нарушение этого подхода.

Comment: @Xzizz Как пример, могу вон дать WPFUI - это некая библиотека для WPF, которая позволяет писать приложения под стилистику современной Win11. Автор там повсеместно [мешает](https://github.com/lepoco/wpfui/blob/main/src/Wpf.Ui.Demo.Mvvm/Views/Pages/SettingsPage.xaml.cs#L15) все, где идет явное нарушение связи, где View слой (страница) знает вдруг про собственный VM слой. Я например сейчас разрабатываю свой проект с ее использованием, и не стал отходить от предложенного подхода, ибо удобно и фиг с ним, мне эта связь не помешает, но это нарушение, да, которое я осознаю. Вот также и вы, думайте..)

Comment: @EvgeniyZ понял - я просто пытался придерживать и не сходить с пути))) хотя у меня получалось решить костылями... короче нужно лучше понять весь синтаксис, ознакомиться с разными подходами, а дальше просто делать всё как считаю нужным...

Comment: @Xzizz Раз напишите на голом MVVM, без лишних библиотек и прочего, а потом решайте как и что делать. Как связать V и VM, я вам дал первым комментарием ссылку, там есть пример, где страница и VM создается **за** пределами, в неком событии запуска приложения. Тем самым мы не нарушаем MVVM, ибо в создаваемых классах нет информации про друг друга, про них знает лишь стартовая точка приложения и ими руководит. Ну а уже потом, из VM можно смело делать другую VM, и так далее. Правда я не знаю как в MAUI (или что там у вас) подобное реализовать, но думаю +- тож самое будет.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Спасибо, буду разбираться)

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Всё как всегда оказалось просто, всё так же через контейнер внедрения зависимостей и запускается по отделбности V, VM и зависимости их. https://github.com/dotnet-architecture/eshop-mobile-client/blob/main/eShopOnContainers/MauiProgram.cs

Comment: @Xzizz Тоже самое [нарушение](https://github.com/dotnet-architecture/eshop-mobile-client/blob/main/eShopOnContainers/Views/BasketView.xaml.cs#L5), где View знает про VM.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ оххх блин)

Comment: @EvgeniyZ ну да, тоже самое только в профиль(

Comment: @Xzizz View не должен знать про VM как минимум по той причине, что View могут делать другие люди, которым не нужны данные, они лишь проектируют UI в виде отдельного проекта. Вон на ответ гляньте, я без проблем могу там вынести все VM слои в отдельный проект, и это все будет без проблем работать, ибо у меня нет связей между слоями. Чтоб была возможность открывать/закрывать окна например, это надо делегировать отдельному "сервису", который будет знать всю информацию, и на основе входного VM открывать нужное ([пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/526028/220553)).

Comment: @Xzizz Если речь про "страницы", то там проще все, ибо вам достаточно один раз указать `DataContext` на главную VM, а дальше, в этой VM вызывать другие VM, на основе которых View подставит нужный вид ([пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/765122/220553)). Но VM слоя внутри View вообще быть не должно, это нарушение MVVM. Но повторю, у каждого "свой MVVM", смотрите свой проект.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ у меня Views и есть Pages), и получается что Pages создают себе VM, с наскока не догнал как сделать иначе... попробую позже перечитать вашим ссылки ещё раз. Спасибо!

Comment: Хочу уточнить для понимания: 1) В первом фрагменте кода "ILogger logger = new Logger();" не должно лы быть "ILogger logger = new FileLogger();"? 2) В третьем фрагменте кода мне кажется подозрительным 2 х "container.Register<ILogger, Logger>();". 3) "Здесь мы зарегистрировали нужные нам типы в контейнере и дальше попросили из него лишь один объект (Program), в который он сам внедрил все необходимые зависимости" - это, вообще, как устроенно? 4) В чём смысл контейнера? Стащить все new в одно место?

Comment: @rotabor 1 - псевдокод, в котором я пытался показать, что может быть любая реализация, поэтому упростил простым `new Logger()`, но в целом да, можно там переписать на `FileLogger`. 2. Очепятка. Я когда пишу ответы, могу раз 10 переписать код в студии, но не поменять до конца в самом ответе. 3. Контейнер автоматически реализует, а также следит за сроком жизни всех объектов, которые требуются для создания запрашиваемого объекта. То есть, при получение класса `Program`, контейнер реализует `ILogger`, а также `SomeClass` (если те есть у него), также реализует и их зависимости тоже.

Comment: Базовую реализацию самого простого контейнера можно посмотреть [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1185026/220553). Ну а на вопрос "Зачем" - это позволяет снизить связанность объектов, ибо почти все объекты, что регистрируются в контейнере пишутся с инверсией (IoC), а это значит, что мы можем удобно их попросить в любом месте приложения, без какой либо инициализации, просто указав свойство, или в конструкторе с нужным типом, контейнер позаботится о сроке жизни, инициализации, и обо всем другом за нас.

Comment: Я для понимания спрашиваю, поймите правильно. В качестве отправной точки. Мне вот это слово"автоматически" не нравится, чувствую в нём подвох. Автоматически - это значит нужно самому ручками эту автоматику запрограммировать. Как контейнер узнаёт, какие зависимости у класса?

Comment: Посмотрел "там". То есть контейнер - это чуть ли не целый фрейворк. Наверняка рефлексию использует.

Comment: @rotabor Я выше дал ссылку на пример самого простейшего контейнера, внимание на метод `Resolve`. Если в двух словах, то контейнер - это некий словарь, которых хранит в себе просто типы, по запросу этот тип достается, получается его конструктор, параметры конструктора, потом эти параметры достаются опять из словаря и инициализируются через `Activator.CreateInstance()`, далее инициализируется основной объект и возвращается. У полноценных контейнеров там есть уйма чего еще, включая срок жизни, и так далее, но в целом, это основной подход.

Answer (score 1):

С точки зрения MVVM всё, что вы описываете — классы работающие прямо или непрямо с аппаратурой — является частью уровня модели.

У вас ещё должна быть бизнес логика (на уровне VM или между VM и M), и собственно UI.

Поскольку и `BleController`, и режимы являются частью модели, поэтому то, как именно они общаются между собой, паттерн MVVM не предписывает.

Для такой простой программы, как ваша, я не вижу необходимости выделения отдельных сервисов, но при усложнении программы такая необходимость вполне может появиться. Не стоит усложнять до тех пор, пока это не является необходимостью.

Ответы на ваши вопросы:

1. Зависит от вас, паттерн MVVM тут стоит в стороне и ничего не говорит. Если вы имеете в виду микросервис, который бежит отдельно и коммуницирует с основной программой по сети, мне это кажется не нужным в вашей ситуации. Создавать имеет смысл либо в начале программы (если данные для создания известны), либо когда будет необходимая информация (если данные вводятся юзером). В любом случае, это вопрос бизнес-логики.
2. Нет, паттерну MVVM всё равно, что делает модель у себя под капотом. Прямое обращение может приводить к слишком сильной связности (а может и не приводить), но это соображение вне паттерна MVVM
3. По идее, это часть бизнес-логики.
4. Модель, плюс вероятно должно быть ещё представление в VM и V
5. Невозможно ответить, необходимо видеть, какое разделение на слои у вас, и как ваши сущности коммуницируют.