# Не обновляется ListBox после удаления элемента

Tags: c#, binding

реализую проект MWWM паттерном, CRUD элементов осуществляется через команды (Lambda(Relay)Command). Не удаляется из View CategorySearchWord после удаления.

Вот View

```
<GroupBox Header="Горячие слова">
                <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding SelectedCategory.CategorySearchWords}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedCategorySearchWord}">
                    <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
                        <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
                        </Style>
                    </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
                    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Grid>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" 
                                           VerticalAlignment="Center" FontSize="16"/>
                                
                                <Button Content="X" 
                                        Command="{Binding DataContext.RemoveCategorySearchWordCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ListBox}}"
                                        CommandParameter="{Binding}"
                                        HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="50"/>
                            </Grid>

                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                </ListBox>
                
            </GroupBox>
```

Команда во ViewModel

```
#region Command RemoveCategorySearchWordCommand - Remove category

        /// <summary>Remove category</summary>
        private ICommand _RemoveCategorySearchWordCommand;

        /// <summary>Remove category</summary>
        public ICommand RemoveCategorySearchWordCommand => _RemoveCategorySearchWordCommand
            ??= new LambdaCommand(OnRemoveCategorySearchWordCommandExequted, CanRemoveCategorySearchWordCommandExequt);

        /// <summary>Checking the possibility of execution - Remove category</summary>
        public bool CanRemoveCategorySearchWordCommandExequt(object p) =>
            p is CategorySearchWord categorySearchWord
            && SelectedCategorySearchWord is not null
            && categorySearchWord is not null;

        /// <summary>Execution logic - Remove category</summary>
        public void OnRemoveCategorySearchWordCommandExequted(object p)
        {
            var categorySearchWord_to_remove = p ?? SelectedCategorySearchWord;

            if (!(categorySearchWord_to_remove is CategorySearchWord categorySearchWord)) return;

            if (!_UserDialog.ConfirmInformation($"Вы уверены, что хотите удалить категорию {categorySearchWord.Name}?", "Удаление категории")) return;

            _CategorySearchWordRepository.Remove(categorySearchWord.Id);

            SelectedCategory.CategorySearchWords.Remove(categorySearchWord);

            if (ReferenceEquals(SelectedCategorySearchWord, categorySearchWord)) SelectedCategorySearchWord = null;

            UpdateCategorySearchWordsView(SelectedCategory); //перевыбирает SelectedCategory для обновления отображения, 

        }

        #endregion
```

При добавлении/изменении View корректно отображает/обновляет данные. Единственное, что у меня корректно сработало для обновления View после удаления, это полная перевыгрузка ObservalCollection из БД...Но это хрень какая-то.
(OnPropertyChanged(...), удаление и добавление обратно в ObservalCollection SelectedCategory целиком тоже результата не дали)

При том при отладке видно что categorySearchWord как из удаляется как из БД так и из коллекции, а в отображении остаётся висеть, при повторном удалении выкидывает ошибку.

```
#region CategoryListBox SelectedCategory

        private Category _SelectedCategory;
        /// <summary>SelectedCategory in CategoryListBox</summary>
        public Category SelectedCategory
        {
            get => _SelectedCategory;
            set => Set(ref _SelectedCategory, value);
        }

#endregion

public class Category : NamedEntity //сущность из БД
{
        public ICollection<ProductBase> Products { get; set; }
        public ICollection<CategorySearchWord> CategorySearchWords { get; set; }
}
```

```
internal abstract class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;



        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string PropertyName = null)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(PropertyName));
}



        protected virtual bool Set<T>(ref T field, T value, [CallerMemberName] string PropertyName = null)
        {
            if (Equals(field, value)) return false;
            field = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(PropertyName);
            return true;
        }
}
```

Экспериментирую тут, вот такой вариант обновляет интерфейс, но это тоже не айс

```
var vvv = SelectedCategory.CategorySearchWords.ToArray();


            SelectedCategory.CategorySearchWords.Clear();  //рабочий вариант, тогда не понятно почему не реагирует на Remove...

            foreach (var item in vvv)
            {
                if (item is null) return;
                SelectedCategory.CategorySearchWords.Add(item);
            }
```

Comment: Что такое `SelectedCategory.CategorySearchWords`? Покажите участок кода по созданию этого объекта (как `SelectedCategory` так и `CategorySearchWords`).

Comment: Добавил, Может это как-то связано с ListBox-ом? Может у него есть какие-то нюансы в отображении данных..?

Comment: П.С. Выгрузку из БД, если это для вас важно, делаю через репозиторий в ObservalCollection "CategoryObservalCollection = new ObservableCollection<Category>(await _CategoryRepository.Items.ToArrayAsync());"

Comment: `ICollection<CategorySearchWord> CategorySearchWords` - а где вы тут увидели `ObservalCollection`? Для обновления интерфейса в WPF есть как минимум 2 интерфейса `INotifyPropertyChanged` - если надо оповестить об изменениях свойства. И `INotifyCollectionChanged` - если надо оповещать об изменениях данных в коллеции. `INotifyCollectionChanged` реализуется по умолчанию в- `ObservableCollection<T>` (ну или можно еще `BindingList<T>`). Собственно, у вас я каких либо механизмов не вижу. То есть вам достаточно `ICollection<CategorySearchWord>` заменить на `ObservableCollection<CategorySearchWord>`.

Comment: Не кажется ли странным вкидывать ObservableCollection в сущность базы данных????

Comment: А это уже косяк с вашей стороны, вашего проектирования. Ведь база это что? Правильно `Model`, так почему идет к ней привязка напрямую из `View` слоя, который вообще не должен знать что-либо про `Model`? В MVVM должно быть `Model <-> ViewModel < View`, то есть мы по клику отправляем команду в `VM`, та запрашивает у `M` слоя нужные данные, сам `M` слой уже идет в базу и формирует ответ, отдавая обратно в `VM`, а `VM` подготавливает свойства для общения с `V` слоем. Ну а у вас просто идет `Model` и `View`, без связующего `ViewModel`)

Comment: Я использую в проекте загрузку данных через репозиторий, вынесенный в отдельную dll, смысл мне создавать дополнительно модели. А даже если делать полноценный слой моделей, то как реализовывать тогда работу репозиториев, учитывая, что у меня так же используется DI? Как на мой взгляд, получится крайне перегруженный код.

Comment: Вы спросили - почему не обновляется? Я вам сказал почему - за обновление UI отвечает `INotify**`, которого у вас нет. Не хотите его использовать - пересоздавайте по новой коллекцию, ваше право. Перегруженность - ну, эта перегруженность дает вам преимущества и строгий контроль всего и вся. `dll` и `DI` - а это тут при чем? У вас нарушение MVVM подхода, проектирования. Вон к примеру я [давал ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1278817/220553), все в своих dll, по своим проектам, связи между друг другом нету, но это же не повод нарушать MVVM...

Comment: Переписал, заработало. Единственный момент для уточнения. В паттерне MWWM Model по факту только описывает используемые в приложении данные и не является их источником.

Comment: Не `MWWM`, а `MVVM` (от слова View). `Model` - это данные, без разницы какие. К примеру - работа с базой данных; или работа с текстовым документом; или общение с сайтом через API или др. механизмы; ну или, к примеру общение с неким устройством (а-ля датчик температуры). То есть в Model делается логика, которая общается с тем или иным источником данных, предоставляя для VM слоя нужное, удобные методы получения необходимого. Вот зачем VM знать, как подключаться к базе, если ей надо только узнать какой баланс у Иванова? Достаточно `model.GetBalance("Иванов");`. Не ленитесь разбивать все на слои!

Comment: С название паттерна да, перепутал. А вот с тем, что модель модель обязательно является источником данных - не согласен. Смотрите, вместо того, чтобы каждый раз писать CRUD для каждой модели, я реализовал:

Comment: `public interface IRepository<T> where T : class, IEntity, new(){
IQueryable<T> Items { get; }
T Get(int id);
Task<T> GetAsync(int id, CancellationToken Cancel = default);
T Add(T item);
Task<T> AddAsync(T item, CancellationToken Cancel = default);
void Update(T item);
Task UpdateAsync(T item, CancellationToken Cancel = default);
void Remove(int id);
Task RemoveAsync(int id, CancellationToken Cancel = default);
}`

Comment: И реализовал использование через контейнер сервисов. На мой взгляд так намного лучше

Comment: Я вам сейчас говорю про то, как должно быть на самом деле, как идет по правилам MVVM. `M` - данные, `VM` - связующий, `V` - интерфейс. Не нравятся эти правила - дело ваше, вас не заставляют, авось изобретете свой велосипед. `так намного лучше` - как лучше, я вам давал ссылку выше. То есть в проекте должна быть минимальная связь, не должно быть вообще `new()`, не должно быть ссылок на другой компонент, каждый класс и метод должны быть самостоятельными, отвечать за одну конкретную задачу, другие подходы имею в себе уйму косяков в дальнейшем (прим: внедрения нового функционала или тестирование).

Comment: И как вы тогда реализуете связь с БД в моделях?

Comment: Я вроде вам уже все сказал, нет? В `M` вы пишете всю логику работы с базой (подключение и др.), она внутренняя. Наружу выдаете простые методы по типу `Add()`, `Get()`, `Update()`, `Delete()` (это уже от задачи). Дале делаете `VM`, в ней инициализируете `M` базы, делаете свойства к которым привяжется `V`, делаете команды, например, `public ICommand AddUserCommand;`, по которой будет вызваться `void AddUser(User user) => baseModel.Add(user);`. Или вон как в валем случае, создание коллекции по команде или как надо - `void GetUsers() => Users = new(baseModel.Get(...));`.

Answer (score 0):

Дописал вот такую модель данных, всё заработало.

```
class CategoryModel : Category
    {
        public CategoryModel()
        {
            ProductsObsColl = (Products is null) ? new ObservableCollection<ProductBase>() : new ObservableCollection<ProductBase>(Products);
            CategorySearchWordsObsColl = (CategorySearchWords is null) ? new ObservableCollection<CategorySearchWord>() : new ObservableCollection<CategorySearchWord>(CategorySearchWords);
        }

        public CategoryModel(Category category)
        {
            Id = category.Id;
            Name = category.Name;
            Products = category.Products;
            CategorySearchWords = category.CategorySearchWords;

            ProductsObsColl = (Products is null) ? new ObservableCollection<ProductBase>() : new ObservableCollection<ProductBase>(Products);
            CategorySearchWordsObsColl = (CategorySearchWords is null) ? new ObservableCollection<CategorySearchWord>() : new ObservableCollection<CategorySearchWord>(CategorySearchWords);
        }
        public ObservableCollection<ProductBase> ProductsObsColl { get; set; }

        public ObservableCollection<CategorySearchWord> CategorySearchWordsObsColl { get; set; }
}
```

Переопределил шаблоны во ViewModel, пара нюансов с конкретизацией сущностей и заработало.