# Где лучше регистрировать типы WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, dependency-injection, autofac

Мне надо регистрировать типы (использую Autofac). Стоит ли нагружать класс `App` в WPF непосредственно регистрацией типов внутри метода `OnSturtup` (объявлять `IContainer`, `ContainerBuilder` итд) или стоит сделать отдельные классы которые будут только регистрировать типы, а затем уже вызывать методы регистрации внутри `OnSturtup`?

Сейчас надо регистрировать 3 типа, однако это только начало.

По идее класс App нужен для определения общих ресурсов для приложения и поэтому можно регистрировать прямо сразу в классе, но тогда класс App будет засорен существованием `IContainer` и прочих сущностей. Не лучше ли вынести это в отдельные классы? А может стоит регистрировать типы вообще где-то в другом месте?

Правда не знаю в каком. Помогите определиться с тем "как правильно"

Comment: Пишите пока всё в `OnStartup()`. Когда вы доберетесь хотя-бы до 100 типов, вы точно будете знать, надо уносить код или нет. Отрефакторить Composition Root в отдельный класс - дело нескольких секунд, независимо от размера кода.

Comment: Лично мне нравится подход как в asp.net core, где все разнесено по сборкам и классам вида `ServiceContainerExtensions` с **методами расширениями** вида `AddFeature(this IServiceCollection...)`, где и происходит регистрация нужного функционала. И в `OnStartup()` подключать это как `services.AddFeature1(); services.AddFeature2()`. И даже в основном ехе такой же класс делать. Читабельно, структурировано, расширяемо.

Comment: @vitidev когда столкнулся с проблемой сразу подумал о таком же подходе как в asp core, но чего-то сложно мне оно всё показалось так как я не особо хорошо знаком с asp

Comment: asp тут никаким боком. Портянку регистраций и так придется распихивать по методам, чтобы ориентироваться как-то. Разница лишь в том - как передать контейнер в этот метод. Ну и где этот метод будет. Метод регистрации фичи будет в той сборке, где сама фича - ведь только там можно увидеть `internal`. Ну а передача контейнера как `this` делает список подключения чище. `services.AddFeature1();`, а не `ExtModuleRegistration.AddFeature1(container)`

Comment: Я вам советую вообще [такой](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1278817/220553) подход.

Comment: Даже если у вас одна сборка, то и там вы можете запихать эти методы в 1 класс,  а можете положить рядом с фичами (которые по папкам разложены) для структурности (весь код фичи должен быть рядом, а не размазан по проекту). Нужно будет - всю эту папку выделим в отдельную сборку. Навигация легкая - прыгаем в `OnStarup` и дальше в нужное место

Answer (score 1):

На мой взгляд, ваш случай хорошо разобран в prism(autofac/unity). Один из авторов сего фреймворка - Brian Lagunas(Microsoft MVP, Xamarin MVP, Microsoft P&P Champion etc). Человек явно что-то понимает в архитектуре приложений, если, по крайне мере, раньше этот фреймворк часто использовали в корпоративных приложениях.

Ниже пример #20

В библиотеке объявляем свой инициализатор:

```
public class ModuleAModule : IModule
{
    public void OnInitialized(IContainerProvider containerProvider)
    {

    }

    public void RegisterTypes(IContainerRegistry containerRegistry)
    {
        //Что-то регистрируем
    }
}
```

В самом приложении добавляем наши библиотеки-модули:

```
public partial class App : PrismApplication
{
    protected override Window CreateShell()
    {
        return Container.Resolve<MainWindow>();
    }

    protected override void RegisterTypes(IContainerRegistry containerRegistry)
    {
        //Здесь регистрируем локальные сервисы

    }

    protected override void ConfigureModuleCatalog(IModuleCatalog moduleCatalog)
    {
        //Наш модуль
        moduleCatalog.AddModule<ModuleA.ModuleAModule>();
    }
}
```

[Примеры(29шт)](https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism-Samples-Wpf)

[PrismApp](https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism/blob/master/src/Wpf/Prism.Wpf/PrismApplicationBase.cs)

[IModule](https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism/blob/master/src/Prism.Core/Modularity/IModule.cs)