# Способы вывода данных из бд sqlite

Tags: c#, wpf, база-данных

в моём проекте WPF я использую два способа вывода данных. В 1 способе через SQLite COMMAND и SQLiteDataReader, а во втором через методы расширения Linq. Все данные берутся из SQLite. Какой способ лучше и правильней использовать, подскажите пожалуйста я новичок в WPF. Заранее спасибо!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
<configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
</configSections>
<!-- Если не работает, то сделайте следующее. Замените все содержимое файла, но объект startup установите такой же, как был у вас ранее  -->
<startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2" />
</startup>
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=D:\C# Project\DrivingApp\DrivingScl.db" providerName="System.Data.SQLite" />
</connectionStrings>
<entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
        <parameters>
            <parameter value="v11.0" />
        </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
    <providers>
        <provider invariantName="System.Data.SQLite"  type="System.Data.SQLite.EF6.SQLiteProviderServices, System.Data.SQLite.EF6"/>
        <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
        <provider invariantName="System.Data.SQLite.EF6" type="System.Data.SQLite.EF6.SQLiteProviderServices, System.Data.SQLite.EF6" />
    </providers>
</entityFramework>
<system.data>
<DbProviderFactories>
        <add name="SQLite Data Provider (Entity Framework 6)" invariant="System.Data.SQLite.EF6" description=".NET Framework Data Provider for SQLite (Entity Framework 6)" type="System.Data.SQLite.EF6.SQLiteProviderFactory, System.Data.SQLite.EF6" />
        <add name="SQLite Data Provider" invariant="System.Data.SQLite" description=".NET Framework Data Provider for SQLite" type="System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteFactory, System.Data.SQLite" />
    </DbProviderFactories>
</system.data>
</configuration>
```

Здесь я подключаю БД.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using System.Data.SQLite;


namespace DrivingApp
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Логика взаимодействия для UserPageWIndow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class UserPageWIndow : Window
    {

        private SQLiteConnection DB;

        public UserPageWIndow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            ApplicationContext db = new ApplicationContext();

            
            DB = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source = DrivingScl.db");
            DB.Open();
            SQLiteCommand cmd = DB.CreateCommand();
            cmd.CommandText = "SELECT id, login FROM Users WHERE id = 3";
            SQLiteDataReader SQL = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            if (SQL.HasRows)
            {
                while (SQL.Read() )
                {
                    nam2.Text += "Логин :" + SQL["Login"];
                }
            }
            else nam2.Text = "Нет таких";

            var query = db.Users.Where(u => u.id == 3);
     
            foreach (var user in query)
            {
                nam.Text = "Login " + user.Login; 
               
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Здесь вывожу логин с id 3 двумя способами в 2 TextBox. Что лучше использовать и вообще профессиональней с точки зрения кода, Если можете пожалуйста развёрнута.
Вот что выводит:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
То что вверху это через SqlAdapter, а внизу методы расширения Linq

Comment: А при чем тут WPF? Тут все зависит от того, как ваш проект построен изначально, какие подходы использует, какие требования к проекту и так далее. WPF это про другое, а именно про MVVM подход, с его привязками и разделением всего на отдельные слои, которые слабо связаны друг с другом, ну а у вас вон контролы дергаются из кода. Выбирайте то, что конкретно подходит под вашу задачу.

Comment: LINQ хорош, когда нужно составлять сложные запросы на лету в зависимости от каких-либо условий. [Why LINQ beats SQL](https://www.linqpad.net/WhyLINQBeatsSQL.aspx). Если у вас не будет таких запросов, то LINQ не особо нужен.

Comment: Кроме того LINQ, а вернее, Entity Framework имеет развитую систему миграций - это очень важно в сложных приложениях, которые будут развиваться многие годы.

Comment: Чтобы создавать сложные проекты(приложения), какой способ будет более читабельным и правильным. Я так понимаю что Методы расширения подходят для простых приложения, а SQLAdapter для сложных или разницы нету? Спасибо за ответы

Comment: Не с того вы начинаете. Еще раз повторю, если вы делаете сложный проект, то там важна архитектура, то, как вы напишете проект, как там будет все взаимодействовать друг с другом, как этот проект будет расширяться и так далее. Вот простой пример, если вы сделаете еще одно окно и вам надо там также найти пользователя в базе, что, будете копировать этот код туда? А если у вас файл базы вдруг поменяет название/расположение, что, будете везде переписывать код подключения? Ок, а если вдруг решили дизайн поменять, без вывода логина на экран, опять полезете в код?

Comment: Раз планируете писать большой проект, правильно, то научитесь писать по правилам MVVM, научитесь делать привязки, это как минимум базовое, что понадобиться. Можете посмотреть на [этот](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1278817/220553) пример, думаю поможет в том, как правильно устроить все в проекте. А база... Почти все используют EF, это удобно, просто, современно, без лишнего геморроя. Ну и он отлично сочетается с паттерном MVVM и IoC контейнерами. Но вам ведь не запрещают писать свои "фреймворки" для базы, опять же, все зависит от задачи.