# Как вызвать метод контрола в VM, не нарушая MVVM?

Tags: wpf

В используемой мной библиотеке WPF-UI есть контрол - snackbar. Мне нужно показать его если произошла ошибка во viewmodel, но вопрос - как? Ведь вызывается он только из код бехайнд, а это уже нарушение его принципов. Ссылка на либу - https://github.com/lepoco/wpfui, ссылка на snackbar контрол - https://github.com/lepoco/wpfui/blob/main/src/Wpf.Ui/Controls/Snackbar.cs.

Comment: https://github.com/lepoco/wpfui/blob/main/src/Wpf.Ui.Demo/Views/Pages/Controls.xaml.cs#L84 и https://github.com/lepoco/wpfui/blob/main/src/Wpf.Ui.Demo/Views/Container.xaml.cs#L62

Comment: а что я должен из этого понять?

Comment: немного разобрался, правда не могу понять почему в результате services.add(MainPage), в код бехайнде возвращает налл

Comment: `а что я должен из этого понять?` - то, как в WPFUI вызывать `snackbar`. За это отвечает сервис, зовется `DialogService`, вам надо его инициализировать, передать в класс окна, там зарегистрировать конкретный `snackbar` через `.SetSnackbarControl(...);`, а дальше, в любом VM слое, передавайте туда `DialogService` (тот, что ранее был инициализирован) и вызывайте его метод `.Show("...")`. Это конечно если не используете IoC контейнеры, без него вы обязаны сами все инициализировать и передавать куда надо, ну а если используете, то `services.AddSingleton<ISnackbarService, SnackbarService>();`.

Comment: Краткое пояснение что такое сервисы, IoC контейнер и прочее - я рассказывал [в этом ответе] (https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1278817/220553), советую изучить. Там правда Prism и DryIoc в качестве основы, но суть не меняет, меняется лишь чуть подход и название методов, ибо в WPFUI из коробки заточено все под IoC от Microsoft, он даже проще и удобней) Так что, если не используете IoC, то советую понять и начать использовать, очень удобная штука!

Comment: я использую, но когда я в код бехайнде пытаюсь заинджектить сервис, чтоб setsnackbarcontrol, он возвращает нулл

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/138656/discussion-between-tynett-and-evgeniyz).