# Как создать правильный файловую архитектуру Xamarin приложения?

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin

**Суть**.
В срочном порядке интенсивно изучаю технологию Xamarin. Мой основной стек технологий это asp.net. Поскольку есть задача для реализации с помощью нового (Для меня) фреймворка, я хотел бы разобраться с правильным подходом к реализации архитектуры. Первым делом я провёл сбор информации и чтение документации. Теперь, перед этапом перехода к реализации и написания непосредственно самого кода и логики работы приложения, меня интересует вопрос об архитектуре.

**Сама суть вопроса**.
Я не могу найти адекватной информации по поводу построения архитектуры приложения. При стандартном создании у меня есть 4 проекта (, .Android, .IOS и .UWP). Я не могу до конца понять по поводу взаимодействия самых компонентов между проектами.

**Вопрос**.
В проекте есть стандартная страница MainPage, внутри которой реализуется стандартная логика для начального экрана приложения. Зачем тогда нужен проект .Android? Если в проект .Android нужно закидывать "экраны" для приложения на платформе Android, тогда какой смысл с проекта ? Какие вообще компоненты нужно добавлять в проект .Android и откуда из вызывать? Если кидать подобную логику в проект , то какой смысл с проектов .Android и .IOS, если всё равно будет вызываться логика с проекта ?

*Пример*.
Если в проекте .Android я создам папку Views и в неё закину экран HomePage.xaml (Правильно ли вообще так делать?), зачем вообще тогда мне нужны подобные папки в проект , если я не имею доступ к вызову событий этих компонентов? Т.е., если у меня есть некая кнопка на экране, который находится в проекте , то как мне привязать вызов этого события из проекта .Android?

**Итог**.
Короче говоря, не могу разобраться по поводу размещения компонентов и их событий внутри проекта, а так же откуда их вызывать, куда передавать. Где вообще нужно реализовать паттерн MVVM, если у меня 4 проекта?

*P.S.*
Я прочитал некую техническую информацию, по поводу самой технологии и как вообще можно реализовать некий, необходимый мне функционал, но я не могу понять, в каком месте его реализовать с точки зрения архитектуры и файловой архитектуры проекта (Не писать же весь код в одном файле, необходимо же всю логику разбивать на множество файлов для создания АДЕКВАТНОЙ архитектуры приложения).

Comment: Если коротко, то .IOS и .Android лишь точки входа, там будут только платформозависимые инфраструктурные вещи. Там не должно быть никакой логики приложения. Я думаю вы поймёте, когда вам правда понадобится туда что-то добавить, а пока не трогайте их.

Comment: @4per, хорошо, а можете ещё не на которые вопрос из поста ответить?)))

Comment: наверняка, нет - не могу. Но на какой именно вопрос? в основном у вас повторяется "Зачем тогда нужен проект .Android?" в разной форме.

Comment: @4per, меня больше интересует взаимодействие между проектами, где и откуда должен происходить вызов событий и обращение к компонентам. Где вообще их правильно размещать? Что на счёт реализации MVVM?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1278817/220553