# зачем создавать объект класса двумя способами

Tags: c#

есть подключенная к проекту сборка "PersonInfo" в котором есть файл "Person". Есть способ 1 создания экземпляра класса:

```
Person p = (Person)Activator.CreateInstance("PersonInfo", "Person").Unwrap();
```

есть обычный способ 2:

```
Person p = new Person();
```

Вопрос: зачем нужен способ 1 если есть простой способ 2 ?

Comment: насколько я знаю, первый способ используют тогда, когда подключаемая сборка динамически подгружается, и может подменяться, не ребилдая основную сборку (так называемый "плагин")

Comment: спасибо большое

Comment: Активатор - это одна из основных частей IoC контейнеров, которые создают и внедряют все зависимости за вас. Плюсы я думаю вы и так уже понимаете, позволяет сделать что-то универсальное, динамичное, не зависящее на одном конкретном типе, что находит много где применения.

Comment: спасибо большое

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Этот пример несовсем правильный. В первом случае как правило явный тип не используется.

Ответ прост, активатор применяется тогда, когда вы не знаете на этапе компиляции, какой тип объекта в этом месте кода предстоит создать. Помимо активатора есть и другие динамические способы создаия объектов.

А явный вызов конструтора используется, когда на момент написания кода, точно известно, какой тип требуется создать в этом месте.

[Вот пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1185026/373567) рабочего использования активатора, где явный вызов конструктора никак не подойдёт.

Comment: спасибо большое вам